# Execute JavaScript code stored as a string

Tags: javascript

How do I execute some JavaScript that is a string?

```
function ExecuteJavascriptString()
{
    var s = "alert('hello')";
    // how do I get a browser to alert('hello')?
}
```

Answer (score 332, accepted):

With the [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) function, like:

```
eval("my script here");
```

> WARNING: Any malicious code contained within the string will be executed with the same privileges of your site, make absolutely sure you can trust the source.

Comment: Be carefull ! This gonna execute the code therefore be careful of where/how you got this string. Mind that anyone may try to insert malicious code inside your string.

Comment: @divinci This is called "Cross Site Scripting". See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting.

Answer (score 184):

You can execute it using a function. Example:

```
var theInstructions = "alert('Hello World'); var x = 100";

var F=new Function (theInstructions);

return(F());
```

Comment: but in the end - isn't that the same as calling `var F=function(){eval(theInstructions);};`?

Comment: yes and no: with eval code would be also executed, while with Function() code isn't executed until F() (use case? check for syntax error but don't want to execute the code)

Comment: @stefan It's beatifull... `new Function("alert('Hello World');")()`

Comment: I tried this inside a try/catch block, and it works perfectly. I can now take any JavaScript code typed into a text block, pass it to my function, and execute it. The catch block can then insert error messages from the JavaScript engine into a DOM element and display any errors in the code. If someone wants the function I wrote, then once I've tidied it up, I can post it here.

Comment: @DavidEdwards Would be awesome if you still have it and post it.

Comment: Would this be faster than using eval() - not considering the part where eval is dangerous, forgetting that now. Is it faster? Or it's all the same because the code is in a string and it gets slow too? (Is the problem of slowness of eval() being in the code being in a string?)

Comment: wrote it into a one liner
`return(new Function ("alert('Hello World'); var x = 100"));
`
no idea if this works, i would reccoment just using `eval`

Comment: One liner should be `return(new Function ("alert('Hello World'); var x = 100")());`

Comment: See an extension of this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66484305/7880517

Comment: variable in the `new Function` will become local scoped variable

Comment: This also has the advantage you can bind an object to the function (using the "bind" method) so you can pass parameters to the statement being evaluated.

Comment: This is better and faster way. With eval you have to parse not only code but also data. If you have variables that contain lots of objects then eval will have to parse it out. With new Function(...).apply(context_with_vars) it evaluates only function code.

Answer (score 72):

The [`eval` function](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp) will evaluate a string that is passed to it.

But the use of [`eval` is ***super dangerous AND slow***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Don%27t_use_eval_needlessly!), so use with caution.

Comment: super dangerous AND slow - you should bold, italic, underline, and h1 that

Comment: I'm doubtful that it's any slower than loading JavaScript anywhere else on the page, that has to be parsed as well. If it's slower, it it's because it's done in a different scope, which might force to creation of resources for that scope.

Comment: If you say `eval()` is dangerous. Is there any alternative?

Comment: @white_gecko It depends on what needs to be accomplished. The "eval can be dangerous" link has a few concrete cases where an alternative to `eval` is available. One thing that is certain is that running `eval` on a user-provided string is a serious security issue.

Comment: @coobird I know this is a little late but why is that dangerous? The user can easily run JavaScript code on your website using the console.

Comment: @jakeimds it can be dangerous if that javascript string is passed to a different user's browser and evaluated there

Comment: if your security depends at all on client-side javascript, you've screwed up big time and it has nothing to do with eval.

Comment: For the people who are wondering why this is dangerous.  If we are allowing eval() on user content say a comment field on your blog site. somebody can write javascript there to steal cookies of other users who are visiting the same page, or redirect users to a  malacious site.  For more info read about cross site scripting.

Comment: The dangerous part is not a user executing code on **their** machine. It is a user executing someone else's code.

Answer (score 35):

For users that are using node and that are concerned with the context implications of `eval()` nodejs offers `vm`. It creates a V8 virtual machine that can sandbox the execution of your code in a separate context.

Taking things a step further is `vm2` which hardens `vm` allowing the vm to run untrusted code.

- https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html - Official nodejs/vm
- https://github.com/patriksimek/vm2 - Extended vm2 (**As of July 2023, this package is deprecated and exposes critical vulnerability**)

```
const vm = require('vm');

const x = 1;

const sandbox = { x: 2 };
vm.createContext(sandbox); // Contextify the sandbox.

const code = 'x += 40; var y = 17;';
// `x` and `y` are global variables in the sandboxed environment.
// Initially, x has the value 2 because that is the value of sandbox.x.
vm.runInContext(code, sandbox);

console.log(sandbox.x); // 42
console.log(sandbox.y); // 17

console.log(x); // 1; y is not defined.
```

Comment: Rather than saying "eval is evil" and giving no context or solution, this actually tries to solve the issue. +1 for you

Comment: What happens if the code is trying to delete or create a file for instance?

Comment: @SteveMoretz Honestly, its been a while since I was using this, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 22):

Try this:

```
  var script = "<script type='text/javascript'> content </script>";
  //using jquery next
  $('body').append(script);//incorporates and executes inmediatelly
```

Personally, I didn't test it but seems to work.

Comment: You forgot escaping closing > in script:  var script = "<script type=\"text/javascript\"> content </script\>";

Comment: Why do you need to escape the closing > ?

Answer (score 21):

Use eval().

[W3 Schools tour of eval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref%5Feval.asp). Site has some usable examples of eval. [The Mozilla  documentation covers this in detail.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)

You will probably [get a lot of warnings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Don%27t_use_eval_needlessly!) about using this safely. **do NOT allow users to inject ANYTHING into eval()** as it is a huge security issue.

**You'll also want to know that eval() has a different [scope](http://piecesofrakesh.blogspot.com/2008/10/understanding-eval-scope-spoiler-its.html).**

Comment: http://www.w3fools.com/. The W3C doesn't even have anything to say about eval. If you want to link to something official, target http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.2.1

Comment: I didn't want to "link to anything official, I wanted to link to something readable - Looking at what *you* linked, it gives no explanation of how it is used, no examples, no way to tinker, and describes the method in isolation. For a beginner, it is a completely inappropriate link. Hey, you wouldn't happen to be @bjorninge, would you?

Comment: The spec describes `eval` better to me than that W3Schools article. Something readable with good explanation and examples would be https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval. And no, I'm not bjorninge

Comment: I will agree that it's not documentation, and I will agree that mozilla's page is a better overall picture of it. Slightly tweaked my answer based on feedback

Comment: Regarding that ecma-international.org link, I would describe it as readable and appreciable by everyone with more than 15 minutes experience with JS. It's very nice.

Answer (score 20):

```
new Function('alert("Hello")')();
```

I think this is the best way.

Comment: Why do you think it is the best way?

Comment: @ggorlen Because it's the most succinct.

Comment: Works great! But fails when i try to put into a function: `function evil(sCmd){
new Function(sCmd))() }`

Comment: @johnywhy Is it? `eval('alert("Hello")')` seems clearly more succinct, so there should be some other reason given as to why this is better than `eval`. I'm asking OP to explain their post, in any case.

Comment: It's the most succinct alternative to eval, which is generally regarded as unsafe, as explained in most answers here.

Answer (score 17):

A bit like what *@Hossein Hajizadeh* alerady said, though in more detail:

There is an alternative to `eval()`.

The function `setTimeout()` is designed to execute something after an interval of milliseconds, and the code to be executed just so happens to be formatted as a string.

It would work like this:

```js
ExecuteJavascriptString(); //Just for running it

function ExecuteJavascriptString()
{
    var s = "alert('hello')";
    setTimeout(s, 1);
}
```

`1` means it will wait 1 millisecond before executing the string.

It might not be the most correct way to do it, but it works.

Comment: Why waste one millisecond when you can pass 0 (zero) to `setTimeout`? Note that in any case it will make the execution asynchronous. It means that all code that follows the `setTimeout` call will be invoked _before_ the code passed to `setTimeout` (even if called with 0 (zero)).

Comment: ‍♀️ just thought it better explained how setTimeout works

Answer (score 9):

Checked this on many complex and obfuscated scripts:

```
var js = "alert('Hello, World!');" // put your JS code here
var oScript = document.createElement("script");
var oScriptText = document.createTextNode(js);
oScript.appendChild(oScriptText);
document.body.appendChild(oScript);
```

Comment: That only works in the browser though js runs in many environments

Comment: The OP asked about browser JS.

Answer (score 7):

Use [eval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref%5Feval.asp) as below. Eval should be used with caution, a simple search about "[eval is evil](http://www.google.com/search?q=eval%20is%20evil)" should throw some pointers.

```
function ExecuteJavascriptString()
{
    var s = "alert('hello')";
    eval(s);
}
```

Comment: Good tip on that *a simple search about "eval is evil"*  Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

New Function and [apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) together works also

```
var a=new Function('alert(1);')
a.apply(null)
```

Comment: This is better than `eval()`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function

Comment: can you use `apply` without the varialbe? The following fails: `("new Function('alert(1);')").apply`

Comment: @johnywhy You need the parameter, it's mandatory as scope https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

Answer (score 6):

If you want to execute a specific command (that is string) after a
specific time 
 - cmd=your  code 
 - InterVal=delay to run

```
 function ExecStr(cmd, InterVal) {
    try {
        setTimeout(function () {
            var F = new Function(cmd);
            return (F());
        }, InterVal);
    } catch (e) { }
}
//sample
ExecStr("alert(20)",500);
```

Comment: @SteelBrain    add a  sample run by ExecStr("alert(20)",500);

Comment: Why is `Val` in `InterVal` capitalized?

Comment: ***InterVal*** is used as an argument, that's why it's capitalized.

Answer (score 5):

I was answering similar question and got yet another idea how to achieve this without use of `eval()`:

```
const source = "alert('test')";
const el = document.createElement("script");
el.src = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([source], { type: 'text/javascript' }));
document.head.appendChild(el);
```

In the code above you basically create Blob, containing your script, in order to create Object URL (representation of File or Blob object in browser memory). Since you have `src` property on `<script>` tag, the script will be executed the same way as if it was loaded from any other URL.

Answer (score 4):

```
eval(s);
```

But this can be dangerous if you are taking data from users, although I suppose if they crash their own browser thats their problem.

Comment: exactly. Eval is dangerous on the server side. On the client... not so much. The user could just type in javascript:someevilcode in to the address of the browser and boom. Eval right there.

Comment: @EsbenSkovPedersen That's prevented in chrome at least, and it requires user action, as opposed to a site that `eval`s code from users, which could for instance let users steal other user's accounts without them knowing just by loading the page.

Comment: @1j01 To be fair my comment is five years old.

Comment: @EsbenSkovPedersen That's true :)

Answer (score 4):

```
function executeScript(source) {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.onload = script.onerror = function(){ this.remove(); };
    script.src = "data:text/plain;base64," + btoa(source);
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}

executeScript("alert('Hello, World!');");
```

Answer (score 4):

An extention of [Stefan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9702401/7880517):

```js
//Executes immediately
function stringToFunctionAndExecute(str) {
    let func = new Function(str);
    return (func()); // <--- note the parenteces
}

//Executes when called
function stringToFunctionOnly(str) {
    let func = new Function(str);
    return func;
}

// -^-^-^- Functions -^-^-^- (feel free to copy)
// -v-v-v- Explanations -v-v-v- (run code to read easier)

console.log('STEP 1, this executes directly when run:')
let func_A = stringToFunctionAndExecute("console.log('>>> executes immediately <<<')");

console.log("STEP 2, and you can't save it in a variable, calling a() will throw an error, watch:")
try {
  func_A();    
} catch (error) {
  console.log('STEP ERROR, see, it failed', error)    
}

console.log('STEP 3, but this will NOT execute directly AND you can save it for later...')
let func_B = stringToFunctionOnly("console.log('>>> executes when called <<<')");

console.log("STEP 4, ...as you see, it only run when it's called for, as is done now:")
func_B();

console.log('STEP 5, TADAAAAA!!')
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is cheating or not:

```
window.say = function(a) { alert(a); };

var a = "say('hello')";

var p = /^([^(]*)\('([^']*)'\).*$/;                 // ["say('hello')","say","hello"]

var fn = window[p.exec(a)[1]];                      // get function reference by name

if( typeof(fn) === "function") 
    fn.apply(null, [p.exec(a)[2]]);                 // call it with params
```

Answer (score 2):

[eval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp) should do it.

```
eval(s);
```

Answer (score 2):

One can use [mathjs](https://mathjs.org/docs/expressions/parsing.html#evaluate)

Snippet from above link:

```
// evaluate expressions
math.evaluate('sqrt(3^2 + 4^2)')        // 5
math.evaluate('sqrt(-4)')               // 2i
math.evaluate('2 inch to cm')           // 5.08 cm
math.evaluate('cos(45 deg)')            // 0.7071067811865476

// provide a scope
let scope = {
    a: 3,
    b: 4
}
math.evaluate('a * b', scope)           // 12
math.evaluate('c = 2.3 + 4.5', scope)   // 6.8
scope.c
```

`scope` is any object. So if you pass the global scope to the evalute function, you may be able to execute alert() dynamically.

Also mathjs is much better option than eval() because it runs in a sandbox.

> A user could try to inject malicious JavaScript code via the
>   expression parser. The expression parser of mathjs offers a sandboxed
>   environment to execute expressions which should make this impossible.
>   It’s possible though that there are unknown security vulnerabilities,
>   so it’s important to be careful, especially when allowing server side
>   execution of arbitrary expressions.

Newer versions of mathjs does not use eval() or Function().

> The parser actively prevents access to JavaScripts internal eval and
>   new Function which are the main cause of security attacks. Mathjs
>   versions 4 and newer does not use JavaScript’s eval under the hood.
>   Version 3 and older did use eval for the compile step. This is not
>   directly a security issue but results in a larger possible attack
>   surface.

Comment: "MAY be able to"?

Answer (score 1):

```
eval(s);
```

Remember though, that eval is very powerful and quite unsafe. You better be confident that the script you are executing is safe and unmutable by users.

Comment: In JS everything can be changed by the user just type "javascript:document.write("Hello World");" into almost any browser's address bar.

Comment: Yes, but you can make it harder for him by not using global variables, hiding your functions in closures etc. Also, by avoiding eval like the plague =)

Answer (score 1):

Using both eval and creating a new Function to execute javascript [comes with a lot of security risks.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Never_use_eval!)

```
const script = document.createElement("script");
const stringJquery = '$("#button").on("click", function() {console.log("hit")})';
script.text = stringJquery;
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

I prefer this method to execute the Javascript I receive as a string.

Comment: How does this mitigate the security risks?

Answer (score 1):

This method avoids use of potentially-risky eval, provides callable functions, uses strict mode on the expression evaluator for extra reliability, and less verbose than other answers.

execute a string command

```
function string_cmd(sCmd) {
    new Function(sCmd)();
}
```

evaluate a string expression

```
function string_exp(sCmd) {
    return Function(
        `'use strict'; 
        return (${sCmd})`
        )();
}
```

usage:

```
const result = string_exp("2+2");

string_cmd("alert(result)");
```

https://codepen.io/johnaweiss/pen/mdKpyZL

Comment: Can i use `strict` on the executor?