# Event on child window refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a child window in Javascript using following code:

```
var wnd = window.open( url );
```

How can i determine whether child window is refreshed or not?
Is there any event for it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080421/retrieve-child-window-reference-after-refresh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's an event for that but you might be looking for the events `unload` and `beforeunload` ([the latter only expecting a string to be shown in a popup](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onbeforeunload.asp)). These are triggered when: closing a window, navigating to a new page or refreshing the actual page.

So in your case you may write something like:

```
var wnd = window.open( url );
wnd.onbeforeunload = function() { do something here }
```

Have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9388380/capture-the-close-event-of-popup-window-in-javascript) for more examples.

Answer (score -2):

var wnd = window.open( url );
wnd.location.reload();

Comment: This doesn't address the question.