# Maximum call stack size exceeded during JSON.stringify(navigator)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am getting RangeError during serialization of Navigator object.

What could be the reason?

```
JSON.stringify(navigator);
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Browser: Chrome
[image]

Comment: You need to show what is inside the navigator object.

Comment: Basically, your navigator object is too big.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because, as the error message says, the `navigator` object is too big.

You can use [dystroy's modified JSON function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14145840/401137) like this:

```
var navJSON = JSON.pruned(navigator);
```

The object returned is pretty huge, but it's almost certain that it isn't completely correct. If you want to transfer data about the `navigator` object using JSON, you *should* send those properties only, not the entire object.

Comment: TypeError: JSON.pruned is not a function

Comment: @kangear Click the link to dystroy's answer for the `JSON.pruned` function

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you copy the specific values you are interested over to a new object and then serialize that instead?

Maybe its finding a property that results in an endless loop.

Comment: I expect it's because the `navigator` object is not standard across browsers, and s/he wants all information available.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe navigator object contain the self-link. You should copy navigator in other object and delete big links on them.