# How to find, where the Javascript keeps an Object I am interested in?

Tags: javascript, reverse-engineering, tree-search

There is a website, which does POST, and I want to know, where parameters are stored. I need it to hack them, edit before posting. Scripts are huge and obfuscated, so I can't find the Objects I need just by reading the source code.

I've tried to serialize the `window` with JSON.prune from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14145840/322020). The keyword, which I use to find, where the string I need is stored, was found near 40 times in 28 megabytes of text. And it is not very readable even after I found substrings. So maybe it is not the way to go.

I need something which would tell me:

- this substr has been detected in:
  -- the String `window.bla_bla_bla.deepobject.bla[5].blabla.msg_to_post`
  -- the String `window.bla_bla_bla.deepobject.bla[3].and_here`
  -- the String `window.and_even_here`
  -- etc.

Answer (score 0):

First, find the function that send POST request.

Is request sent when you click button? [visual event](http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event) can help you find it.

Next, Read the function and overwrite it with your own.

If scripts are minified, use beautifier like [this](http://jsbeautifier.org/)

Normally, with Chrome developer tool and visual event I got all thing want to know.