# How do I JSON.stringify a large JSON object without hanging?

Tags: json, node.js

I have a massive JSON object (170k lines, around 130Mbs). When running

```
var stringified = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);
```

My node.js application hangs and then times out

How can I stringify such a large file without having it timeout?

Comment: related: [JSON.stringify deep objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13861254/json-stringify-deep-objects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the problem wasn't a result of the large JSON, it was something else...

However, in the process I found that you can use lodash _.chunk to split the json into smaller parts for parallel processing.

```
var arr = _.chunk(largeObj, SIZE_OF_CHUNKS);
```

Comment: And the "something else" was what?

Comment: It was over 4 years ago, I don't remember... but it was not JSON... probably XML or CSV