# JSON.stringify() Does Not Work As Expected

Tags: javascript, json, stringify

I have used `JSON.stringify()` many times and I am aware of some issues such as (described in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13861254/json-stringify-deep-objects)):

- cycles
- too deep objects
- too long arrays

However, I am facing incorrect stringify operation on object which is like that:
[image]

After running JSON.stringify(obj) on console, I am getting that.

```
"[{"$$hashKey":"object:103",
 "ProductCategories": [{"Id":2,"ShopProductCategoryName":"Drink","isSelected":true}
                       {"Id":3,"ShopProductCategoryName":"Food","isSelected":true}]
 }]"
```

It only stringifies `ProductCategories` and `$$hashKey` which is totally unexpected.

---

### Solving Attempts

If I create new object from `obj` and stringify it, returns correct JSON.

```
var newObj = { // Creates new object with same properties.
  AllProductCategories: obj.AllProductCategories,
  Id: obj.Id,
  LabelName: obj.LabelName,
  Percentages: obj.Percentages,
  ProductCategories: obj.ProductCategories
}

JSON.stringify(newObj); // Returns correct JSON.
```

I used the code to send object to web api compulsorily, but the way is not what I want, of course.

---

As I see,

- There is no cycles.
- It is not too deep. (only has depth 3)

Therefore, I cannot figure out what is wrong.

Comment: Do note that console.log is asynchronous while JSON.stringify is synchronous. Are you sure the properties you show on your screenshot (which looks to be from the console) are already present when you call stringify?

Comment: Without seeing code that replicates the issue the best we can do is throw blind guesses.

Comment: Does it real properties, or inherited from prototype? JSON.stringify ignores prototype, while console.log shows all enumerable properties.

Comment: @Juhana there are lots of code to form an object like that, there is a problem with only `JSON.stringify(obj)`.

Comment: @doldt `console.log` isn't necessary asynchronous, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/23392650/1092711

Comment: I'm sure there is, but if we can't reproduce the problem it's not really possible to solve it.

Comment: @doldt Yeah, i'm sure because `console.log(obj)` and `JSON.stringify(obj)` successive operations.

Comment: @AlexeyTen they are real properties

Comment: Don't you have method `.toJSON`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#toJSON_behavior

Answer (score 0):

Well I suggest you create a function that clones your object without `$$hashKey` property that was set by angular I guess:

```
function cloneObj (obj) {
   var cloned = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
   delete cloned.$$hashKey;
   for(var key in cloned) {
      if(typeof cloned[key] === 'object') {
         cloned[key] = cloneObj(cloned[key]);
      }
   }

   return cloned;
}
```

After you clone your object without `$$hashKey`, then you can stringify it without any problem.

Comment: Angular comes with its own [`angular.toJson`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.toJson) that leaves out the $$ properties. There's no reason to strip them out manually.