# Cordova Android console log object

Tags: cordova

Working on using the datawedge plugin in my apache Cordova app. I have built the functions and getting a callback from the plugin. The problem is, its an object and I am not sure whats in the object. I am trying to console log, using the cordova plugin. In the log its returning [Object, Object]

What can I do to see whats in the object?

```
onDeviceReady: function() {

    LineaProCDV.initDT(onDeviceConnected, onBarcodeScanned);
    datawedge.start();

    datawedge.registerForBarcode(function(data) {
        console.log("Results!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
        console.debug(data);
    });

    app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `JSON.stringify(data)` which will go to a certain depth of nested object.  If you need to go deeper take a look at options [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13861254/json-stringify-deep-objects).

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer given previously, to actually log the output of an object in Cordova:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
```