# Why JSON.stringify() returns empty result for some objects

Tags: javascript

This question is so basic, yet I have no idea of the answer.

Why `screen` object when stringified returns empty?

Does this mean `JSON.stringify()` needs read/write access to the input?

```js
let a = {foo: 'one', bar: 2};


console.log(JSON.stringify(a));
console.log(JSON.stringify(screen));
```

Comment: @Variable https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/screen . If it was never declared you'd get an error about it being undefined.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stringify DOMWindow object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079653/stringify-domwindow-object)

Comment: @ADyson Thanks, didn't knew about this, learned something new :D. 

Comment: @user202729 I think the answer here is better than the one in the duplicate. I'll change the tittle so that it's more general.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

FROM MDN Network

For all the other Object instances (including Map, Set, WeakMap and WeakSet), only their enumerable properties will be serialized.

> Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/propertyIsEnumerable

```js
    console.log((window.screen));
    console.log(JSON.stringify(window.screen));
    console.log(window.propertyIsEnumerable(screen));
```

Comment: Actually, most of the (popular) answers on this site are just a docs-quote. That is a proper answer (as long as you quote important parts and not just a link)