# Javascript - Pass window as a variable

Tags: javascript, session, window, store, session-storage

Here is what I'm trying to do:

- when the user signs up I store the current window in a variable and I send him an email:

  `<script>sessionStorage.setItem("window", window)</script>
  <?php
      sendEmail(/*...*/);
  ?>`
- when the user opens the email, I get the previously saved window from the storage and close it

  `<script>sessionStorage.getItem("window").close()<script>`

This would prevent the browser from having too much unuseful windows opened on the same domain.

The problem is that I get an error like this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: sessionStorage.getItem(...).close is not a function
```

(same result if I previously store it on  variable)

---

Furthermore, when I log the current window I get an object containing every method:

```
Window {parent: Window, opener: null, top: Window, length: 0, frames: Window, …}
alert: ƒ alert()
...
```

when I log the stored function I just get this:

```
[object Window]
```

---

Is there a way to achieve my goal?

Is it possible to pass a window as a simple variable?

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because `sessionStorage` does not store *objects* but *strings*. What you need to do to add an object to the storage is to stringify it when writing and parsing it when reading:

```js
sessionStorage.setItem('test', JSON.stringify({ value: 'this is a test' }))
JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('test'))
```

While this will work *most* objects, `window` sadly enough is not one of them because it contains circular references (ie: it references itself) You can read more about that problem here: [Stringify DOMWindow object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079653/stringify-domwindow-object)

Comment: I tried with this: `sessionStorage.setItem(\"window\", JSON.stringify({ value: window }))` but it does not work... [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6012438/13327421) answer says that it it impossible to stringify a window... Could it be the case?

Comment: Did your script open the window in the first place? If not then you cannot close it using javascript. If you use a service worker then you can reclaim all the windows open on your domain using that.

Comment: @miknik I've not opened the window with javascript, but I thought that since I'm passing the variable from the window itself I could close it...

Comment: Nope, sorry. See the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close)

Comment: @miknik a workaround like opening a new tab and closing the current one? or is it better to give up?