# JSON serialize a DOM element

Tags: javascript, json

If I do:

```
var el =
{
   o : document.createElement("iframe")
}

var fs = JSON.stringify(el);

and then I try to access with

var ofs = JSON.parse(fs);
```

`ofs.o` contains an empty object not the iframe elements WHY??

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2303713/how-to-serialize-dom-node-to-json

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JSON (*JavaScript Object* Notation) is **not** designed for serializing DOM Nodes, you'll need to pull out the stuff you want by yourself and write it to an object, and then re-create the DOM Nodes from that if you need.

In fact, Chrome doesn't even execute your code:

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
```

Answer (score 2):

I did it like this.  I put the code on [github](https://gist.github.com/1298684)

```
function elementToObject(element, o) {
    var el = $(element);
    var o = {
       tagName: el.tagName
    };
    var i = 0;
    for (i ; i < el.attributes.length; i++) {
        o[el.attributes[i].name] = el.attributes[i].value;
    }

    var children = el.childElements();
    if (children.length) {
      o.children = [];
      i = 0;
      for (i ; i < children.length; i++) {
        child = $(children[i]);
        o.children[i] = elementToObject(child, o.children) ;
      }
    }
    return o;
  }
/*
  exemple:
  a = elementToObject(document.body);
  Object.toJSON(a);
*/
```

This javascript function convert any element to an object, then you can convert it to json.

Answer (score 1):

Building on Alain's prototypejs code, I've updated it using underscore and jQuery, also put into a gist [here](https://gist.github.com/fracmak/7452752)

```
function elementToObject(element, recurse) {
    var el = $(element),
        o = {
            tagName: el[0].tagName
        };

    _.each(el[0].attributes, function(attribute){
        o[attribute.name] = attribute.value;
    });

    if (recurse) {
        o.children = _.map(el.children(), function(child){
            return this.elementToObject(child, true);
        }, this);
    }
    return  o;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function elementToObject(element) {
    var el = $(element)[0];
    var o = {tagName: el.tagName};
    _.each(el.attributes, function(attribute){o[attribute.name] = attribute.value;});
    o["children"]=_.map($(el).children(), function(child){return elementToObject(child)});
    return o;
}
```

This is working with jquery 3.1.0 and underscore.js.