# Can I extend the console object (for rerouting the logging) in javascript?

Tags: javascript, logging, extend

Is it possible to extend the console object?

I tried something like:

```
Console.prototype.log = function(msg){
    Console.prototype.log.call(msg);
    alert(msg);
}
```

But this didn't work.
I want to add additional logging to the console object via a framework like [log4javascript](http://log4javascript.org/) and still use the standard console object (in cases where log4javascript is not available) in my code.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why are you extending the prototype object instead of extending the `Console` object itself? Do you ever call `new Console()`?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Try following:

```
(function() {
    var exLog = console.log;
    console.log = function(msg) {
        exLog.apply(this, arguments);
        alert(msg);
    }
})()
```

Answer (score 5):

It's really the same solution some others have given, but I believe this is the most elegant and least hacky way to accomplish this. The spread syntax (...args) makes [sure not a single argument is lost](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13017382/2214704).

```
var _console={...console}

console.log = function(...args) {
    var msg = {...args}[0];
    //YOUR_CODE
    _console.log(...args);
}
```

Comment: nice use of the spread/rest syntax, but its not needed, theres a 1 line smaller way that supports IE an doesnt overwrite protos above.

Answer (score 4):

You Can Also add log Time in This Way :

added Momentjs or use **New Date()** instead of   moment.

```
var oldConsole = console.log;
console.log = function(){
    var timestamp = "[" + moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss:SSS") + "] ";
    Array.prototype.unshift.call(arguments, timestamp);
    oldConsole.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

Comment: This doesn't work as it generates a "moment is not defined" error.

Comment: you have to install moment using npm install moment

Comment: ok, I guess, I'd prefer a native solution though. For example NPM is yet "another" thing that needs to be present

Answer (score 2):

### For ECMAScript 2015 and later

You can use the newer [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) feature from the [ECMAScript 2015](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/ECMAScript_2015_support_in_Mozilla) standard to "hijack" the global [console.log](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Console/log).

### Source-Code

```
'use strict';

class Mocker {
  static mockConsoleLog() {
    Mocker.oldGlobalConsole = window.console;

    window.console = new Proxy(window.console, {
      get(target, property) {
        if (property === 'log') {
          return function(...parameters) {
            Mocker.consoleLogReturnValue = parameters.join(' ');
          }
        }

        return target[property];
      }
    });
  }

  static unmockConsoleLog() {
    window.console = Mocker.oldGlobalConsole;
  }
}

Mocker.mockConsoleLog();

console.log('hello'); // nothing happens here

Mocker.unmockConsoleLog();

if (Mocker.consoleLogReturnValue === 'hello') {
  console.log('Hello world!'); // Hello world!
  alert(Mocker.consoleLogReturnValue);
  // anything you want to do with the console log return value here...
}
```

### Online Demo

[Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/ViciousColdStruct).

### Node.js users...

... I do not forget you. You can take this source-code and replace `window.console` by `gloabl.console` to properly reference the console object (and of course, get rid of the `alert` call). In fact, I wrote this code initially and tested it on Node.js.

Comment: this is enormous compared to the answer above with a 6 line overwriter, I think this is overkill for a simple function rewrite

Comment: No, do not use proxies to hijack a single property.

Answer (score 1):

```
// console aliases and verbose logger - console doesnt prototype
var c = console;
c.l = c.log,
c.e = c.error,
c.v = c.verbose = function() {
    if (!myclass || !myclass.verbose) // verbose switch
        return;
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments); // toArray
    args.unshift('Verbose:');
    c.l.apply(this, args); // log
};

// you can then do
var myclass = new myClass();
myclass.prototype.verbose = false;
// generally these calls would be inside your class
c.v('1 This will NOT log as verbose == false');
c.l('2 This will log');
myclass.verbose = true;
c.v('3 This will log');
```

I noted that the above use of Array.prototype.unshift.call by nitesh is a better way to add the 'Verbose:' tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the default behavior of the `console.log` function using the below approach, the below example demonstrates to log the line number using the overridden function.

```js
let line = 0;
const log = console.log;
console.log = (...data) => log(`${++line} ===>`, ...data)

console.log(11, 1, 2)
console.log(11, 1, 'some')
```