# Can I display console.log messages on Iframe

Tags: javascript, html

Can I display console.log messages on Iframe if yes can then please also tell me how to display it, I am creating a vary simple JS game and I want to display my logs on iframe.

Comment: i think you need to override console.log method to wirte on an iframe

Comment: What do you mean console logs on iframe? In my experience, console.logs in iframes show from the parent window, too.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9277780/can-i-extend-the-console-object-for-rerouting-the-logging-in-javascript ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following approaches:

- **change your logging** so that you can target both console and [some iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997986/write-elements-into-a-child-iframe-using-javascript-or-jquery). This has the advantage that you can have a separation between what is displayed on screen and what is logged, but you have to work more
- **[override console.log](http://udidu.blogspot.co.il/2012/12/override-console-functions.html)**, so that you can also do something else with output data