# Saving The Console via Javascript

Tags: javascript, console, save

I am wondering if there is a way to save the entire console to a file using javascript. I am outputting to the console a counter number and the text of a div which repeats itself x amount of times depending on how many divs are on the page and I want to save everything that is in the console. My console looks something like this:

> Div: 34 | Title: Some Title
>
> Div: 35 | Title: Some Other Title
>
> Div: 36 | Title: Yet Another Title

I would like to save all those lines to a file using javascript. So that it does it automatically when the divs are done being displayed. Is there a way to do this?
Thank you for your time.

Edit:
https://jsfiddle.net/u4ohzofk/

```js
var titles = $('.title');
for(i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
 console.log("Div: "+i+" | Title: "+$(titles[i]).text());
}
```

```html
<div class="title">
Here is a title
</div>
<div class="title">
Here is a title2
</div>
<div class="title">
Here is a title3
</div>
<div class="title">
Here is a title4
</div>
<div class="title">
Here is a title5
</div>
<div class="title">
Here is a title6
</div>
<div class="title">
Here is a title7
</div>
<div class="title">
Here is a title8
</div>
<div class="title">
Here is a title9
</div>
<div class="title">
Here is a title10
</div>
```

I have created the above fiddle to further help me explain what I am looking for. I have divs with titles that I get off of a page. I number the divs and grab their titles and then spit that out into the console. I then want to save the entire console when it is done spitting out the divs. I want to do this automatically through javascript. Not manually. I am also not just inputting this into a variable because other elements are automatically displaying to the console that I am looking to save as well.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: This is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). The console is only displaying what you tell it to. Show the relevant code and explain in more detail what higher level problem you are trying to solve

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I extend the console object (for rerouting the logging) in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9277780/can-i-extend-the-console-object-for-rerouting-the-logging-in-javascript)

Comment: Also possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11849562/how-to-save-the-output-of-a-console-logobject-to-a-file

Comment: I found an answer here: http://bgrins.github.io/devtools-snippets/#console-save. Hope this can help you

Comment: I have created an example of what I am looking for. https://jsfiddle.net/u4ohzofk/

Comment: Everything that was posted above I already tried before I asked this question. Those are still manually. I am looking to be able to just save the console as a whole through javascript without having to tell it what objects I am looking to save. I just want a file to be created containing all that is in the console at the time of creation. Line breaks would be nice too.

Answer (score 0):

- In Chrome, right-click in the console and choose `Save As...` and
  you're good to go.
- In Safari, use `Cmd-S`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I knew about this. I have also found some other plugins but I want to code it and I wanted to see if there is a more simple way than the current plugin out there because I just want to save the entire log as it is. Thanks.