# Change console.log message color

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console.log

Is there a way to do something like:

```
console.log("hello world", '#FF0000')
```

in Chrome/Safari or Firefox ?

Comment: Same question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505623/colors-in-javascript-console

Comment: No, that's not the same question. Please remove your close request. In the question you referenced, the guy wants to change the color for ALL log messages. I would like to change it on a per message basis.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I'm not sure how to remove my close request. I don't see anything to do that.

Answer (score 65):

You can use the following:

```js
function colorTrace(msg, color) {
    console.log("%c" + msg, "color:" + color + ";font-weight:bold;");
}
colorTrace("Test Me", "red");
```

Comment: this will give wrong line number in the output - it will show the line where  actual native `console.log` invoked

Comment: @godblessstrawberry - correct, just replace the variable in the function with console.log("%c my message", "color:#993333;font-weight:bold;");, I put the function in for convenience as the original question didn't specify what was preferred so I optimized for re-use.

Comment: @Shane what are you talking about? I'm saying this function solution is useless in terms of debugging as it always will point to the wrong line where `console.log()` was invoked not where `colorTrace()` was called

Answer (score 34):

Made this and its been helpful:

```
function log(msg, color) {
    color = color || "black";
    bgc = "White";
    switch (color) {
        case "success":  color = "Green";      bgc = "LimeGreen";       break;
        case "info":     color = "DodgerBlue"; bgc = "Turquoise";       break;
        case "error":    color = "Red";        bgc = "Black";           break;
        case "start":    color = "OliveDrab";  bgc = "PaleGreen";       break;
        case "warning":  color = "Tomato";     bgc = "Black";           break;
        case "end":      color = "Orchid";     bgc = "MediumVioletRed"; break;
        default: color = color;
    }

    if (typeof msg == "object") {
        console.log(msg);
    } else if (typeof color == "object") {
        console.log("%c" + msg, "color: PowderBlue;font-weight:bold; background-color: RoyalBlue;");
        console.log(color);
    } else {
        console.log("%c" + msg, "color:" + color + ";font-weight:bold; background-color: " + bgc + ";");
    }
}
```

Use:

```
log("hey"); // Will be black
log("Hows life?", "green"); // Will be green
log("I did it", "success"); // Styled so as to show how great of a success it was!
log("FAIL!!", "error"); // Red on black!
var someObject = {prop1: "a", prop2: "b", prop3: "c"};
log(someObject); // prints out object
log("someObject", someObject); // prints out "someObect" in blue followed by the someObject
```

Comment: I love the function you've put together, very nice. However, the default case in your switch statement is unnecessary, as it's not actually doing anything, other than taking up a cycle.

Comment: Good point. One could check if a color is given and only then run the switch.

Comment: this will give wrong line number in the output - it will show the line where  actual native `console.log` invoked

Answer (score 10):

**ALL of currently given answers will cause major debugging issue** - the line number reported in the log output will always correspond to the line where the custom log function ultimately invokes the native `console.log`

Simple coloring is available in the regular `console.log` - just prepend first parameter with `%c` and pass stringified css rules as a second parameter:

```
console.log(`%c[stackoverflow] postAnswer()`, ';background: lightblue; color: #444; padding: 3px; border-radius: 5px;');
```

This is how it looks in the console:
[image]

Proper logging wrapper you could find under this answer

> [A proper wrapper for console.log with correct line number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13815640/a-proper-wrapper-for-console-log-with-correct-line-number)

**For VSCode users:**

Here's keybindings snippet that wraps your clipboard into nice log and allows you to choose the color:

```
{
    "key": "cmd+alt+l",
    "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "args": {
        "snippet": "console.log(`%c[${WORKSPACE_NAME/(.*)/${1:/upcase}/}] ${CLIPBOARD}`, '${2|;background: lightblue; color: #444;,;background: lightgreen; color: #444;,;background: lightsalmon; color: #444;,;background: lightcyan; color: #444;,;background: lightpink; color: #444;,;background: lightseagreen; color: #444;,;background: lightskyblue; color: #444;,;background: lightsteelblue; color: #444;,;background: khaki; color: #444;,;background: purple; color: white;,;background: salmon; color: white;,;background: blue; color: white;,;background: #444; color: white;,;background: green; color: white;,‍♀️;background: blueviolet; color: white;,;background: chocolate; color: white;,‍;background: mediumvioletred; color: white;,;background: brown; color: white;,;background: cadetblue; color: white;,;background: cornflowerblue; color: white;,;background: crimson; color: white;,;background: red; color: white;|} padding: 3px; border-radius: 5px;');"
    }
}
```

just add this entry into your keybindings.json - on mac its here:  `~/Library/Application Support/Code/User/keybindings.json`

This is how it looks in VSCode:

[image]

Comment: Which wrapper will accept the necessary second argument for colorization? There are a lot of answers and most rely directly on bind, which doesn't let you bind trailing arguments.

Comment: I don't use wrappers, I use my vscode snippet which is enough for my debugging purposes

Answer (score 2):

You with the following snippet you can use the console.log command as you wished!

- Chrome ✔️
- Firefox ✔️
- Safari ✔️

```js
(function () {
    $consoleLog = console.log;
  console.log = function ($message, $color) {
    $consoleLog('%c' + $message, 'color:' + $color + ';font-weight:bold;');
  }
})();

console.log('test', 'green');
```

OR

https://jsfiddle.net/mL88u3n9/

Comment: this will give wrong line number in the output - it will show the line where  actual native `console.log` invoked

Comment: Also loses the ability to log actual objects. Will only output `[object, object]`

Comment: @JohanAspeling did you find a solution for %c for objects?

Comment: @ManoharReddyPoreddy unfortunately not, we decided to remove this logging functionality after a while as too many logs made the console quite colourful.. :sweat_smile:

Comment: @JohanAspeling just add this `if (typeof message === 'object') console.log(message);` to treat objects differently and works with the rest

Answer (score 2):

You can add functions to the object `console`, for example I use this function for success

```js
console.success = (message) => { 
  console.log('%c ' + message, 'color: green; font-weight:bold') 
}

console.success('I am a successfull message')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by Jaden's answer. Made a little log function.

```js
function log(msg, color) {

  var css = "",
  paint = { // default colors
    clr: "#212121",
    bgc: "#b0bec5"
  },
  colors = {
    error: {clr:"#ffebee", bgc:"#c62828"}, // red
    success: {clr: "#e8f5e9", bgc: "#2e7d32"}, // green
    warning: {clr: "#fff3e0", bgc: "#f4511e"}, // orange
    info: {clr: "#ede7f6", bgc: "#651fff"} // purple
  };

  // overriting default colors if color given
  if (colors.hasOwnProperty(color)){ paint.clr = colors[color].clr; paint.bgc = colors[color].bgc; }
  css = "color:" + paint.clr + ";font-weight:bold; background-color: " + paint.bgc + "; padding: 3px 6px; border-radius: 2px;";

  console.log("%c"+msg, css);
}
```

Test

```js
log("Default");
log("Error", "error");
log("Success", "success");
log("Warning", "warning");
log("Info", "info");
```

[What it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EiBdE.png)

Comment: this will give wrong line number in the output - it will show the line where  actual native `console.log` invoked