# Node console wrapper with noop

Tags: javascript, node.js, console

I'd like to use a [modified version of this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32928812/1682405), to wrap console logging into a new function:

```
function Logger(force) {

    const logging = {};

    if (force) {
        for (let m in console) {
            if (typeof console[m] == 'function') {
                logging[m] = console[m].bind(console);
            }
        }
    } else {
        for (let m in console) {
            if (typeof console[m] == 'function') {
                logging[m] = function() {};
            }
        }
    }

    return logging;
}

debugOff = new Logger(false);
debugOff.log("this WILL NOT log");


debugOn = new Logger(true);
debugOn.log("This WILL log");
```

However, I'd like to *not* create a new instance of the `Logger`, and just pass `true/false` with the relevant `string`. I've tried wrapping the new instance in another function, but I'm having to use a specific method in it:

```
function noopLogger (force, string) {

    function Logger(force) {

        const logging = {};

        if (force) {
            for (let m in console) {
                if (typeof console[m] == 'function') {
                    logging[m] = console[m].bind(console);
                }
            }
        } else {
            for (let m in console) {
                if (typeof console[m] == 'function') {
                    logging[m] = function() {};
                }
            }
        }

        return logging;
    }

    instance = new Logger(force);
    return instance.log(string); // don't want to do this here
}

noopLogger(true, "this will log"); // this logs, but I only have access to log, not warn, error, etc.
```

How can I refactor this so I can call:

```
noopLogger.log(true, 'this WILL log'); 
noopLogger.log(false, 'this WILL NOT log');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this fulfills your requirements. Let me know if you are looking for something more or something else.

```
function getLogger() {
  const logger = {};

  for (let m in console) {
    if (typeof console[m] == 'function') {
        logger[m] = function (force, string) {
          if (!force) return;
          console[m].call(console, string);
        }
    }
  }
  return logger;

}

const noopLogger = getLogger();
noopLogger.log(true, 'this WILL log'); 
noopLogger.log(false, 'this WILL NOT log');
noopLogger.warn(true, 'this warning WILL log');
noopLogger.warn(false, 'this warning WILL NOT log');
```

Output:

```
:> node test.js
this WILL log
this warning WILL log
```

Comment: `logger[m] = function (force, string)` is the expression that was eluding me. I was getting hung up on the binding. That's very much @Neeraj Sharma