# Wrapper console log color and line

Tags: javascript, console

I have this :

```js
  //define in utils.js
   function l (message) {
    if (message.includes('success')) {
        return console.log.bind.call(console.log, console, `%c%s`, `color:green;`)
    } else {
        return console.log.bind.call(console.log, console, `%c%s`)
    }
}
   

    l("success to import")("success to import") // execute in index.js
```

It work because I have the good color and the good row (from index.js and NOT utils.js).
But I want to be able to only write `l("success this check work", some var,...)`

And Not with two pair of parenthesis ...

I want to have a wrapper function which could change color based on log content :
If I have succes I want green log 
If I have error I want red log
And display the correct log row, not from utils.js but from other file js where it's called

[image]

Comment: Instead of `var l = (function(message){. . .})`, why not just have: `function l(message){. . .}`? Also, wrapping the function in parenthesis here does nothing.

Comment: it's the same result

Comment: Why are you binding to the console? You would only be doing that if you were overriding the original.

Comment: I know. That's what I was trying to point out. Your code is more complicated than it need be. It's always best to start with the simplest code possible.

Comment: If you doesn't bind it you will lose the row number, some it will tell me it's executed from my utils.js

Answer (score 1):

I will recommend create a object to separate out method, like success, fail. However, still needed follow the below syntax. This sample is for node js.

```js
const logger = {
  log: (...messages) => console.log("\x1b[36m%s\x1b[0m", ...messages),
  info: (...messages) => console.log("\x1b[36m%s\x1b[0m", ...messages),
  warn: (...messages) => console.log("\x1b[33m%s\x1b[0m", ...messages),
  error: (...messages) => console.log("\x1b[31m%s\x1b[0m", ...messages),
  success: (...messages) => console.log("\x1b[32m%s\x1b[0m", ...messages),
  _raw: console.log
};
const l = (...messages) => {
  if (messages.length === 1) {
    if (messages[0].indexOf("success") !== -1)
      console.log(`%c${messages[0]}`, "color: green; font-size: 16px;");
    else if (messages[0].indexOf("error") !== -1)
      console.log(`%c${messages[0]}`, "color: red; font-size: 16px;");
    else console.log(`%c${messages[0]}`, "color: blue; font-size: 16px;");
  } else console.log(...messages);
};
l("success to import"); // execute in index.js
l("error to import");
```

Comment: It said , it's execute from utils.js (where I copy past  your function) 
But I want the row number in index.js file (where I copy l("error to import");)

Comment: u cant use the context

Comment: How could I print the trace?

Comment: yes coz u are passing context. here u calling as method.

Comment: If u have error, just print error, not the message.

Comment: but that's not what I want :D

Comment: I struggle the same :-D. u can create context in start of the file. and than return methos

Comment: Could you write me an example of that? please

Comment: I try tomorrow! too late here! really sorry :-D

Comment: for u i found this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13815640/a-proper-wrapper-for-console-log-with-correct-line-number