# how to console.log the number of the line in the code

Tags: javascript

how to console.log the line number of the called function or console.log()

for example in the IDE i can see the line like this. how can I show that by console.log it

```
14 
15 // other code/logic
16
17 console.error(`error at line ${herePutTheLogic}`);
18
```

output: `error at line 17`

[image]

Comment: https://kaihao.dev/posts/console-log-with-line-numbers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A proper wrapper for console.log with correct line number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13815640/a-proper-wrapper-for-console-log-with-correct-line-number)

Comment: If you're coding into VSCode, [Turbo Console Log](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ChakrounAnas.turbo-console-log) might be right choice if you don't want to go deep into creating your own solution for it!

Comment: Similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340872/how-to-get-javascript-caller-function-line-number-and-caller-source-url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `(new Error()).stack` to get the stack trace at the current line. it would require some additional parsing to get the line number however.

e.g., `console.log((new Error()).stack.split(':')[1])` will get it assuming it is at the root of the file, but once you start adding it to functions you'd need something a little more sophisticated.

```js
console.log(
  "❌ the error is on the line N." +
  new Error().stack.split(":")[3]
);
```

Comment: it give me `//stacksnippets.net/js` as output here on stack

Comment: Looks like you have a URL in your stack trace, you need to account for that in your index choice

Comment: ok I will try with localhost and tell you if is working, I upvoted in the main time

Comment: My example is very brittle, you will need to customize the parsing done for your use case. try console logging without the split and you will see the line numb/column at the end of each file URI

Comment: I saw now someone edited your answer, and is super correct now (with also code snippet), thanks