# Multiple color change in console.log?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, console, console.log

I just read [this SO question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9332979/change-console-log-message-color) and it said to change the color, use

```
console.log("%cYour Message Here", "color:(your color);font-weight:bold;");
```

I have tested this and messed around with it a bit, and changed it to

```
console.log("Test\n\n%cTest\n\nTest", "color:red;font-weight:bold;");
```

this outputs (where the bolded text is also red)

> Test
>
> **Test**
>
> **Test**

Is there a way to cause the output (where bold is red and italics is blue)

> Test
>
> **Test**
>
> *Test*

Comment: More info here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505623/colors-in-javascript-console

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
console.log("Test\n\n%cTest\n\n%cTest", "color:red;", "color:blue;");
```

I do however feel that the following is much more readable.

```
console.log("Test");
console.log("%cTest", "color:red");
console.log("%cTest", "color:blue");
```

Check https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console-api#consolelogobject-object for a full reference.

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log("Test");
console.log("%cTest", "color:red;font-weight:bold");
console.log("%cTest", "color:blue;font-style:italic");
```