# Google Chrome console format html

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to make Google Chrome console to format output `html`. So if I will

```
console.log('<ul><li>1</li><li>2</li></ul>');
```

It will show real list instad of html markup

Comment: **Note:** Dont use `console` in live.

Comment: Know it, Its debugging purpose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it does not seem possible. The [Console API reference for Google Chrome](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console-api) mentions no such thing.

You can however create a debug `div` tag and add your contents to that:

```
<div id='debug'></div>
```

and

```
document.getElementById('debug').innerHTML = '<ul><li>1</li><li>2</li></ul>';
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple hack might be something like this:

```
console.html = function(data){
   var self = this;
   for(var i=0; i< arguments.length;i++){
      var wrapper= document.createElement('wrapper');
      wrapper.innerHTML = arguments[i];
      self.log(wrapper)
   }
}
```

Comment: This comment expands on Akhil's answer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505623/colors-in-javascript-console#comment23574763_13017382

Comment: For me, this does _not_ output formatted HTML in the console.

Comment: which browser are u using

Comment: @AkhilSekharan: I'm on Google Chrome for Mac, version 28.0.1500.71 (up to date).

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

you can show a list using

```
console.log("hi",[1,2,3,4],"ho");
```

(The `,` are important, `+` will convert the array into String.

No, plain html is not possible.

[image]