# Convert string into fancy log message

Tags: javascript, console.log

I want to console log a `string`, say for example `" Ajey Charantimath".`

But I want to make it appear all fancy in the console of the browser.

Examples to check out- 
1) https://www.khanacademy.org. (Open the console in the browser and you can see a fancy font of the string "Khan Academy"
2) http://www.flipkart.com/ (same log in the console)

I know this can be achieved by doing a console log in the application and trying to align the characters and stuff.

But is there an automated way of achieving this ?
Wherein I will just enter the string and its formatted in the correct way?

Comment: Look for ASCII generators, here is one example: http://www.network-science.de/ascii/, and here is another: http://patorjk.com/software/taag/#p=display&f=Graffiti&t=Type%20Something%20

Answer (score 5):

You can take a look at [this awser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505623/colors-in-javascript-console#13017382). By starting your message with `%c`, you can add style in the second parameter of `console.log()`.

Example:

```
console.log('%cAjey Charantimath', 'background: red; color: white');
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also use image to create ascii art for you try http://www.ascii-art-generator.org/

Answer (score 0):

That's [ASCII art](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii_art). You can either generate it by hand or use a library, for example jsascii as suggested in [this blog post](http://blog.nihilogic.dk/2008/03/jsascii.html).