# How to apply CSS to console.log coloring automatically

Tags: javascript, command-line-interface, console.log

We can stylize console log outputs in browsers. But, how to use the same console.log calls to stylize in command line?

I'm aware of how to colorize console outputs. What I want is: Just calling the below code, it will colorize in CLI automatically; a tool or a way to do that.

**Convert CSS to Commandline automatically**

```js
console.log('%c COLORFUL', 'background: orange; color: white;');
```

**@Oleg @Bergi this question is not a duplicate. Please read the questions carefully before marking.** This question has been marked incorrectly as a duplicate.

Comment: You mean for use in node.js for example?

Comment: @tobspr Yes. I'm getting console messages from my app in phantom js through CLI. But, they come unformatted because of CSS.

Comment: @Oleg no, it's not. I'm not referring to CLI coloring. I'm referring to CSS to CLI coloring.

Comment: As far as I know, there's no tool that uses CSS styles to colorize a CLI output.

Comment: An [easy/simplest way do it to show colors in console](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42551926/3240038)

Answer (score -2):

Have a look at [color.js](https://github.com/marak/colors.js/). It provides functions to stylize the console output.
Usage is as simple as:

```
console.log("Yellow text".yellow);
```

Comment: You should clarify your question then, because right now thats not obvious

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, as OP wanted a way to convert css console.log styling to node.js , like you do with color.js.

Answer (score -2):

You can use a library, such as [chalk](https://github.com/chalk/chalk).

```
const chalk = require('chalk');

// combine styled and normal strings
console.log(chalk.blue('Hello') + 'World' + chalk.red('!'));
```

Comment: @InancGumus You could replace console.log with a function that calls both for you: `const log = text => console.log(chalk.blue(text));`

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The question asks how to convert the %c to node.js style, like chalk here.