# How to provide styled text in console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-console

If one goes to Facebook and opens the console they'll see input such as this:

[image]

How does Facebook achieve this styled text? Also, unlike a normal `console.log`, etc. there is no `script.js:123` reference in the console. This is Chrome 56.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13017382/340760

Comment: Here is a similar question with an answer from the guy who created it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21693931/746736

Comment: After literally 3 hours on this, all I've come up with is ugly CSS hacks and `eval("function foo(){console.log('Blah blah blah');} foo();//# sourceURL=.");
`... but I have learnt loads of cool things after having actually read a ridiculous amount of MDN's documentation... ha... who knew... Oh, and Facebook still has the source URL for me, so my guess is some option in Chrome (but we don't really want that now, do we ;)). Good luck, I'll come back to this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please Refer to this for examples on how to add colors to console:  [Colors in JavaScript console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505623/colors-in-javascript-console?rq=1)

In short :

With Chrome & Firefox (+31) you can add CSS in JS `console.log()` messages:

```
 console.log('%c Oh my heavens! ', 'background: #222; color: #bada55');
```

[image]

Comment: I initially marked this question as a duplicate of the one you reference but it doesn't answer the question of why there is no script reference

Comment: You could always create the JS in the server side and log as a console log which would not create any references if the JS is created and logged dynamically. It would involve many more steps, but can be done