# How to log html to console - Javascript

Tags: javascript, console.log

I'm trying to log ***html*** to the browser's console in order to notify user, for example, when user open developer tools a header logged to console.

Just like Facebook

[image]

I have tried this,

```
console.log('<h1 style="color : red">Pay Attention</h1>');
```

but it's logged as string

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505623/colors-in-javascript-console

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
console.log('%c Stop ', ' color: red; font-size:28px;');
```

you cand find all by googling customize javascript console