# Is there any way to change the color of error message when I use throw statement?

Tags: node.js, colors, console, throw

I know some tools to change console's text color, such as [chalk](https://github.com/chalk/chalk) . But when I use `throw` statement to print error message and need to red it:

```
const chalk = require('chalk');

throw new Error(chalk.red('some error messages'));
```

It failed with no red color's error message:

```
?[31msome error messages?[39m
```

Is there any way to change the color of error message caused by `throw` statement?

Comment: Where exactly do you try to see the color? With console.log?

Answer (score 1):

You have to put your **throw()** call in a **try/catch** block. This way, you can catch your error and format it with **console.log()**.

Example:

```
// The try/catch block
function run() {
    try {
        myAction();
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log('%c ' + err.message, 'background: red; color: white');
    }
}

// Your action 
function myAction() {
    throw new Error('some error message');
}
```

Now you can just call **run()** and see the formatted error in the console.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this using `ASCII escape code` for red color in my `throw new Error(errorToShow)`.

I just added `\x1b[31m` at beginning of the string a want to format and `\x1b[0m` to the end of it.

To make this nicer, I used a `const` to interpolate my error message and then pass to `throw new Error(errorToShow)`

```
const formattedError = `Can be whatever you what to show: ${anotherThingToShow}`

// Applying red ASCII escape to make error more visible
const redFormattedError = `\x1b[31m${formattedError}\x1b[0m`

throw new Error(redFormattedError);
```

Keep in mind that in this way you are actually throw an error that potentially can stop your code. This solution is useful only when you want to stop the execution and print a more visible error.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your console understands [ANSI sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code)? I mean, the browser console may not understand them at all, and Windows command line displays them properly only in Windows 10.

Generally you should avoid throwing ANSI-colored error messages, as it may not work on every system, and thus is a bad practice. Nevertheless `throw` alone should not break the sequence, as it is just a string of ASCII characters.

What may break it is console itself not understanding it. What you have pasted (`?[31msome error messages?[39m`) differs from a valid ANSI-colored text only by replacing the escape character (ASCII code 27) with "?". Thus I suspect you are trying to display the text in a console not suitable of interpreting ANSI codes. Use Windows 10 console or any Unix/Linux/MacOS X system console and it will work. In the consoles of webbrowsers and in Windows versions prior to 10 it won't.

If you need colored console output in webbrowser [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505623/colors-in-javascript-console#13017382).