# Colors in JavaScript console For NativeScript debugger tool

Tags: javascript, nativescript

I am trying to get colorful console for Nativescript application for debugging mode. When we use

```
tns debug android/ios
```

We get a URL to use in chrome for debugging like this

```
chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/inspector.html?experiments=true&ws=localhost:40000
```

I have tried few suggestion as listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505623/colors-in-javascript-console) to use CSS in console e.g.

```
const warningTitleCSS = 'color:red; font-size:60px; font-weight: bold; -webkit-text-stroke: 1px black;';
console.log('%cStop!', warningTitleCSS);
```

but it simply prints

```
%cStop! color:red; font-size:60px; font-weight: bold; -webkit-text-stroke: 1px black;
```

is it something related to chrome debug tools or am I trying something wrong here?
[image]

Comment: You're missing a space between %c and Stop

Comment: I have tried console.log('%c Oh my heavens! ', 'background: #222; color: #bada55'); with space after %c and it is simply printing %c Oh my heavens!  background: #222; color: #bada55

Comment: Are you actually doing this in chrome or an emulated android or IOS browser? I just tried this on chrome and it works... I literally copy pasted your code into the browser console...

Comment: I am doing this in chrome.

Comment: open your devtools and try this does it work there?

Comment: Yes, it works if I copy and paste same code in devtools in console but it does not work if I paste in chrome-devtools console. I have share that screenshot in question Looks like chrome-devtools:// issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181579/discussion-between-daniel-tate-and-narendra).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NativeScript console is actually an implementation of the native logs (e.g. the LogCat for Android). The console.log is a stub JS class which actual implementation is overwritten in the native projects. So it does not have much in common with the Chrome console and this said - the NativeScript console is not supporting the CSS properties.

Note: the option to apply colors is logged as a feature [here](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/719)