# util.inspect - make string red if number is 0

Tags: node.js

I have this object:

```
{
  services:
   { 'account-service': 1,
     'activity-service': 1,
     'cancellation-service': 1,
     'chat-service': 1,
     'integrator-service': 1,
     'lh-app': 1,
     'notification-service': 1,
     'patient-web-app': 0,   // make this line red if 0
     'reminder-service': 1,
     'rest-service': 1,
     'shortener-service': 1,
     'socket-service': 1,
     'tunnel-service': 1,
     'web-app': 1 } }}
```

if one of the numbers is 0, I would like to be red instead of yellow. Anyone know of a way to create a custom util.inspect function that can do this?

[image]

Comment: Could you adapt [techniques like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505623/colors-in-javascript-console)?

Answer (score 4):

When you `JSON.stringify` the output from `util.inspect` with its `colors` option set to true. For instance;

```js
console.log('%s', JSON.stringify(util.inspect(obj, { colors: true })));
```

it reveals the ANSI color/formatting codes applied.

Given your `patient-web-app` property with its value set to `0` you'll see it is formatted as:

> `\u001b[32m'patient-web-app'\u001b[39m: \u001b[33m0\u001b[39m,\n`

Consider using a regexp to perform a replacement. For instance:

```js
const util = require('util');

const obj = {
  services: {
    'account-service': 1,
    'activity-service': 1,
    'cancellation-service': 1,
    'chat-service': 1,
    'integrator-service': 1,
    'lh-app': 1,
    'notification-service': 1,
    'patient-web-app': 0,   // make this line red if 0
    'reminder-service': 1,
    'rest-service': 1,
    'shortener-service': 1,
    'socket-service': 1,
    'tunnel-service': 1,
    'web-app': 1
  }
}

const colorizedZeroValues = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(util.inspect(obj, { colors: true }))
      .replace(/(: \\u001b)(\[33m)(0\\u001b\[39m,\\n)/g, '$1[31m$3'));

console.log('%s', colorizedZeroValues);
```

**Prints**

[image]

Comment: yeah I am not a fan of regex in general, it's hard to update 2 months later when you no longer understand the regex...I wonder if there is a formatter "callback" function we can use

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `util.inspect.custom` symbol to return a custom string that will be logged to the console as-is when `inspect` is called on it.

[Here is the official documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_custom_inspection_functions_on_objects).

### Example: custom `console.table` rendering

`console.table` actually calls `inspect` on every cell value to render. If you want to have custom rendering on a cell, just make it an object with the `[util.inspect.custom]` property returning your custom string:

```js
import colors from 'colors/safe';  // i want to use custom colors

// ...

// utilty function to make any result render as-is
function overrideInspect(result) {
  return {
    [util.inspect.custom](depth, options) {
      return result;
    }
  };
}


function renderUsers(users) {
  const table = [];
  for (const user of users) {
    // ... get all our data ...
    let modInfo = '';
    if (role >= ModeratorRole) {
      modInfo = colors.yellow(' M');
    }

    // add to table
    table.push({
      name: overrideInspect(displayName + modInfo), // append yellow `M` to white name if it's a mod
      email,
      signup,
      stats,
      uid
    });
  }

  // render table
  console.table(table, [
    'name',
    'email',
    'signup',
    'stats',
    'uid'
  ]);
}
```