# JavaScript console style entire log

Tags: javascript, console.log

How do I style and entire `console.log`?
`"%c Text"`, `"style"` obviously works for strings, however that only works on the text in the string after the `"%c"` and not for objects etc, 
In my case I'm creating a new function for specific cases, e.g.

```
var fancyLogger = function(){
    var newSet = [
        "FancyLog",
        window.specificItem,
        ...arguments // includes non-strings
    ];
    // This but with say font-size: 300%
    console.log.apply(console, newSet);
};
```

EDIT: To confirm, I don't want to change the styling on the whole console.
EDIT2: I also need to change mroe than just colour so bash flags won't work here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Colors in JavaScript console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505623/colors-in-javascript-console)

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52733695/11265949

Comment: Bash colour flags don't work for font-size and I don't want to restyle the whole console.

Comment: I don't get it. _"...works, however that only works on the text in the string after the "%c"_ - is it a trouble?

Comment: Objects aren't strings so can't be prefaced by "%c"