# Colorizing specific words in the browser console

Tags: javascript, browser, colors, console

I'm trying to help my colleagues by creating usefull and easy to read console messages. Therefore I dived into colorizing them based on how important the information is I want to convey. I got the basics already, like colorizing the whole line with

```
console.log('%cThis will be red', 'color: red')
```

But I wanted to take things one step further and highlight specific words with different colors. But I can't find a way colorize only a single word, without affecting the rest of the sentence.

I know about

```
console.log('%cThis will be red, %cbut this will be blue', 'color: red', 'color: blue')
```

but I want to just colorize a single keyword. Is it possible to reset the color at a specific position in the string? Can I scope the css to a specific part of the string?

Comment: I think the answer on this page is what you need. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505623/colors-in-javascript-console

Comment: Can you maybe tell me where? I already looked through that question many times but couldn't find an answer to my specific problem of stylizing a specific party of my string. Maybe I just overlooked it...

Comment: you can use third-party library like chalk https://github.com/chalk/chalk