# How to change the color of a string in the chrome console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I know how to change the color of the first line.

```
console.log ( '%c%s', 'color:' + color, str )
```

But my string looks like this.

```
console.log('%c'+ args[args.length-1], 'color:' + color,performance['now'](true, args[args.length-1]),'[(', ...args.slice(0, args.length-1),'*)',`${message}`,']')
```

It is give my this result:
[image: It is give my this result:]

How can I change my console.log so that the message '~~~~~~~~~ example ~~~~~~~~~~' also changes color ?

Addition:

I don't understand...

All examples are of the form

```
console.log ( '%c%s', 'color:' + color, str )
```

I made one line of this kind and my color is preserved.
But here is another problem.

```
    console.log(`%c ${args[args.length-1]} ${performance['now'](true, args[args.length-1])} [(${args.slice(0, args.length-1)} *) ${message}]`, 'color:' + color)
```

result:

[image: result]

But how do I display objects in expanded form?

When trying to add a second color to the console, she does not see this.

```
console.log('%c'+ args[args.length-1], 'color:' + color,performance['now'](true, args[args.length-1]),'[(', ...args.slice(0, args.length-1),'*)',`%c` +`${message}`,']','color:' + color)
```

result:

[image: result]

Addition:

result your:

[image: result one]

```
   console.log('%c%O' + ' '+ args[args.length-1],'color:' + color,performance['now'](end, args[args.length-1], message),'[(', ...args.slice(0, args.length-1),'*)',message,']')
```

result what i use:

[image: color not work]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try this for a sec: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505623/colors-in-javascript-console

Comment: I will add a Supplement: I do not see how to solve the problem (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your format appears to be just a little off:

```js
// Run this in devtools
let example1 = 'performance';
let example2 = JSON.stringify({JSON: {select: 1,transformWith:()=>{}}},null,2);
let message = '~~~~~~~~~ example ~~~~~~~~~';

console.log(`%c${example1}\r\n%c${example2}\r\n%c${message}`, 'color:#bada55', 'color:#ba0055', 'color:#1ada55');
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: It is great example !!! thank you !!!

Now i have two version is output.

Your version color true.
But i need create object.

And now i use version there color not work but compact view

Example in addition.