# How to make padding spaces results of a similar length when using non alphanumeric characters?

Tags: javascript, typescript, unicode, padding, non-alphanumeric

I am using javascript, and I want the output of the following `console.log()` to be of a same length.

```
const str1 = 'English';
console.log(str1.padEnd(10, '.'));

const str2 = '日本語';
console.log(str2.padEnd(10, '.'));
```

However, the current output is as following:

```
> "English..."
> "日本語......."
```

My desired output is as following:

```
> "English..."
> "日本語....."
```

I am trying my example based on the explanation here [String.prototype.padEnd()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padEnd)

How to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried adding monospace font to the console logs?

Comment: No, I don’t know how to do that. Do you have any helpful guidance for this?

Comment: This should help adding css to console.log https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505623/colors-in-javascript-console you should be able to add a font-family

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I think that's not exactly what I want. For example, how that could be applied using my example on this page? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padEnd

Comment: I mean if I copy/paste my code and try the output, how can I get the desired output based on your suggestion? I will add the desired output to my question.

Answer (score -1):

For doing this you can find the length of both strings using the length() methods of javascript and then add the padEnd method according to the difference

```
const str1 = 'English';
const str2 = '日本語';

const a=str1.length;
const b=str2.length;

const c= a-b;
console.log(str1);
console.log(str2.padEnd(c,'.'))
```

This will also make the whole thing dynamic as well

Comment: Have you tried your code on the page I mentioned in my question? I tried it there and it gave me the following error: `Error: str1.length is not a function`

Comment: Basically, what the `length` returns is the count of the characters in the string. What I want is the "real" space that is taken by the character.