# JS - Is there a way to add CSS styles to JSON console log messages without losing default functionality?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome-devtools

I recently found out you can add colors and basic CSS to `console.log()` calls with the use of the `%c` character. (Learned about it from this answer [Colors in JavaScript console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505623/colors-in-javascript-console))

It works well for `string` values. However, I tried logging an array, and got a pretty disappointing result. It logged it as `[object Object]`, instead of giving me an interactive view of the array, and the ability to expand it, so I could look at the objects inside.

I am aware you can use `JSON.stringify` to see **ALL** the content, but I want the default functionality of `console.log` so I can fold and expand at will, to avoid clutter in the console.

Is there a solution for this?

**Code I have used:**

```
console.log(`%csuccess`, 'background-color: #2FA745; color: #fff; display: block; padding: 4px;');
const myArray = [{test: 'hi'},{test2: 'hello'}];
console.log(`%c${myArray}`, 'background-color: #2FA745; color: #fff; display: block; padding: 4px;');
console.log('default behaviour of array', myArray);
```

[image]

Comment: Not that I know, but you can use `%c${JSON.stringify(myArray)}` so you'll at least see the contents.

Comment: @ChrisG I am aware of JSON.stringify, however i want the default functionality so i can expand and fold at will, so it wont clutter up the console.

Comment: @DanielB. There is no other functionality to color the console with just doing this `%c${myArray}` You have to use `JSON.stringify` if not then i would rec-emend dont use color.

Comment: Another option for (multidimensional) arrays and objects (or objects inside arrays) is the `console.table()` function. Doesn't give you CSS styling but it really helps with the readability

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is console.logging a bunch of colored dashes before and after the array.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of. You can use `JSON.stringify`, but I'm sure that's not what you're looking for. You can't style them with the usual functionality (drop downs, prototype, etc...) because they need to be strings to be styled. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Per the [specification for console.log](https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#formatting-specifiers) you should use `%o` and other substitutions:

```js
console.log(`%c%o / %c%d %c[%s]`,
  'color: red', [{test: 'hi'},{test2: 'hello'}],
  'color: green', 123,
  'color: cyan', 'foo');
```

Comment: I tried running this code. The first styling (color red) is being applied to the '/' character and not to the array.

Comment: Of course, for that you'll have to use [Custom Formatters](https://www.google.com/search?q=devtools+Custom+Formatters).