# Console.log CSS style in template literals

Tags: javascript, css, console.log

I'm creating a game played in the console and I would like to decorate my `console.log` messages to give them more flare.

Since I'm new to coding, I'm trying to learn to use template literals any time I `console.log` a message.

If I reverted to quotes and concatenation, I could style my console.log messages like so: `console.log('%c some message' + someVar, 'color: red')`

How can I style my `console.log` messages using template literals?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Colors in JavaScript console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505623/colors-in-javascript-console)

Comment: console.log(\`%c some message ${someVar}\`, 'color: red')

Comment: What makes you think that template literals work differently when applying colors to them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this type of formatting.

```js
console.log(`%c ${message} ${someVar}`, `color:${color}`)
```

Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a template literal for the first argument to `console.log` instead of concatenation.

```
console.log(`%c some message ${someVar}`, 'color: red')
```

You can also use dynamic styles by using a template literal for the second argument as well.