# Confusion in console or How to find by seeing if an item is Data-type Undefined, or String Undefined, should Google improve Console for Strings?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

In the following code-snippet, the equation is manipulated right-to-left. typeof x returns `undefiend` (but in string format), which gets stored in `var x`. Now, we know `"undefined" !== undefined`, as they are 2 different data-types.

Don't you guys think, Chrome is acting weird or Not-upto-the-mark by showing both the 2 items in same format in console-window? Isn't it wrong behavior? Please, help explain if I am right saying, Chrome should depict `"undefined"` with double-quotes in console (To remove the confusion). Is this something that developers at Google missed out, or they did not care or they let this behavior (strings wihtout quotes in console) intentionaly?? I am confused. Pls, suggest your views.

```js
var y = 1, x = y = typeof x;
console.log(x);
console.log(x === undefined);
console.log(x === "undefined");
console.log("undefined");
```

```js
a = "Peter"; b = "Jacob";
console.log(a, b, "Ronald");
```

Comment: Yes, they look same, but one is a data-type (`undefined`), other one is data-type(`string`) whose value is undefined. So, by looking there is no way I can differentiate. I am saying shouldn't google improve showing string-with-undefined-value as `"undefined"` at console? Won't this be better and clear for users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's how all logged strings render in Chrome: black, without delimiters.

The *value* `undefined` is distinguished by color, but it's kind of hard to see - unlike strings, `undefined` the value is slightly grey-ish instead of black:

```js
console.log("undefined");
console.log(undefined);
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBkAp.png">
```

Yeah, IMO it could definitely stand to be more obvious.

A weird hack you could implement to make it clearer would be to patch `console.log` and [apply CSS of your own](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505623/colors-in-javascript-console) when the value is `undefined`.

```js
const origConsoleLog = console.log;
console.log = (...args) => {
  if (args.length > 1) origConsoleLog(...args);
  const [arg] = args;
  
  // customize...
  if (arg === undefined) origConsoleLog('%cundefined', 'font-weight: bold; color: grey');
  else origConsoleLog(arg);
};

console.log("undefined");
console.log(undefined);
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFFMC.png">
```

You could apply this to all sites with a userscript if you wanted, so you don't have to add it each time.

Comment: Vow! That level of detailing I was expecting. Thanks, ... it helps, but still for color-blinds or "Web-Accesibility", don't you think, Google should anyways attach double-quotes. Though now I understand, they did try to make some difference - to help end-user! Your suggest would help.

Comment: You can use `%o` to give it the same format as the console. e.g. `console.log('%o', yourval);`