# Debug messages show blue in Chrome DevTools

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

I'm making a game and I added some debugging messages with `console.debug()` but I noticed they were showing blue:

[image: Screenshot]

The code was the following:

```js
console.debug('Reduced bounce on body because difficulty is on', difficulty);
```

I didn't add any styles to the message, it's something that Chrome did.

Chrome version `103.0.5060.114 (Official Build) (x86_64)`, on macOS

Comment: I have the same version, I don't see this.

Comment: That's just the color of "debug" level console messages in Chrome in dark mode on MacOS.  see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505623/colors-in-javascript-console)

Comment: @James if you post that as an answer I will accept it

Comment: @James I still don't see the blue color in the dark mode on MacOS. Can you share some screenshot with your observation?

Comment: @PankajParashar check the screenshot in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blue with a light blue "message count" badge is the default color or Chrome debug-level console message on MacOS in dark mode.

Some info about how to change the default for your own browser, or ways to write console messages in your own colors is in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505623/colors-in-javascript-console)

Here's a screenshot from my Macbook:

[image: MacOS dark mode screenshot console]