# Some console message text grey in color in chrome dev tools?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, google-chrome-devtools

When I open console in Chrome Dev tools I can see **some console messages are in grey text** and some others in normal text. Why some console messages are in grey color?

[image]

I am using react and debugging my app using Chrome Dev tools, mostly by **console.log** method in Typescript.

**My Research**
I have found my threads explaining how we can set colors for console messages. But that is not what I am looking for.

**My Question**
I want to know why some messages are grey in console.

Comment: Is there a link to the app where we can see these console messages?

Comment: If possible could you share a snippet of the code that generates these log messages?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Colors in JavaScript console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505623/colors-in-javascript-console)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The messages are dimmed by the React Developer Tools extension. In strict mode, React calls many functions (components, effects, ...) twice, and console log invocations from the second call are dimmed. They wouldn't happen at all in production.

It's also described in React docs on strict mode: https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html