# How to console.log objects as a color?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, console.log, ansi-escape

(node.js) if i try to color an object on console.log like so

```
console.log('\x1b[32m', {a:1,b:2,c:3}, '\x1b[0m');
```

it looks like this:

[image]

how do I make it so the text actually all gets colored?

I know i could stringify the arguments manually then join them to  a single string and color them, but that ruins the nice multiline formatting console.log usually employs:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps this will help: [colors-in-javascript-console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505623/colors-in-javascript-console)

Comment: Looks like you are fighting against the console styling an object. Maybe convert the object to string if you really want it green.

Comment: I tried converting it to a string, but that puts the objects all on one line instead of how they're normally printed in a nice formatted way.

Comment: What `console` implementation are you asking about? It looks a bit like a nodejs environment or something else that writes to a terminal, but it will work very differently e.g. on the web.

Comment: yeah sorry should have said it's node.js in the vscode terminal

Comment: @RyanWilson Probably not, that's asking about Chrome console

Comment: Probably better to use a library like [Chalk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chalk) than bash around with raw ANSI.

Comment: See https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#customizing-utilinspect-colors

Comment: yeah im actually using chalk, but it doesn't solve this problem. passing in an object still only colors the first line/ section.

Comment: @RyanWilson The accepted answer (and the other answers with the same approach) work *only* in browsers, not in the terminal, which is what the OP is asking about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to convert an object to a pretty json string you may pass a 3rd param as the indent size for beautify-ing the input.

```js
var obj = {
  some: "thing",
  values: {
    arr: [12, 15, 24],
    size: null
  }
}

console.log("this is a string: " + JSON.stringify(obj, null, 4))
```

Then of course you can colorize it using one color. See comments above for techniques.

Comment: How does this even remotely answer the question? The question is about coloring the text printed to the console. `"how do I make it so the text actually all gets colored?"`

Comment: It answers one of the comments about convert to string creates one line string

Comment: he's right actually!

Comment: `JSON.stringify` is **not** the "*the nice multiline formatting `console.log` usually employs*". [`util.inspect`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#utilinspectobject-options) is much more elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to set `FORCE_COLOR` environment variable to `1` / `2` or `3`.
[See docs for more details](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#force_color1-2-3)

Node JS has built in support for colors so simply:
`console.log('Some text', someObject)` will work just fine.

Azure pipelines supports `2`.