# How do I show an entire javascript object as a string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

As a feature in a sort of game created in HTML5/CSS in combination with javascript, I would like to show some randomly looking code which scrolls in a div.

An easy way to accomplish this would be to actually print the code used to create the game, but I cannot seem to manage to do so.

I have tried to call .toString() on an object I have defined, but it only prints [Object Object], which obviously isn't preferably. The desired effect is basically the same as calling .toString() on a single function, however I would like to do so on the entire code/all objects that I use.

How could I accomplish this?

Edit:
Some clarification, I have an object

`var Foo = {
   stuff: [], 
   function1: function() { /* code */ } 
}`

And I would like to be able to use it as follows:

`var string = Foo.toString();
$("#myDiv").html(string);`

Which will result in myDiv containing the source code of the object called Foo.

Comment: have you tried `JSON.stringify()`?

Comment: @PlantTheldea Yes, JSON.stringify() gives me an "Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON" error.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616630/json-stringify-avoid-typeerror-converting-circular-structure-to-json

Comment: You should just use AJAX to get the file contents. Converting an object to "source code" is way too hard.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer you are looking for:

[How to inspect Javascript Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5357442/how-to-inspect-javascript-objects)

You have to *navigate* the object, there is no function as PHP's `var_dump`.

Answer (score 0):

here is something you could use :

```
var a = {'some':'strange','object':''};
console.log( JSON.stringify(a) );
// outputs : {"some":"strange","object":""}
```

If your game is targeting IE > 9, then you could further randomize the string with something like (base64 encode/decode):

```
var a = {'some':'strange','object':''};
console.log( btoa(JSON.stringify(a)) );
// outputs : eyJzb21lIjoic3RyYW5nZSIsIm9iamVjdCI6IiJ9
```