# Can't print a value in JS object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to print a value stored in a JS object but I don't know how can I access it. Here's my code:

```
var the_votes = {
    "Heredia": {
        voters: 70000,
        parties: {
            pln: 0,
            pac: 0,
            plib: 0,
            rc: 0
        }
    },
    "San Jose": {
        voters: 200000,
        parties: {
            pln: 0,
            pac: 0,
            plib: 0,
            rc: 0
        }
    },
    "Alajuela": {
        voters: 80000,
        parties: {
            pln: 0,
            pac: 0,
            plib: 0,
            rc: 0
        }
    },
    "Cartago": {
        voters: 50000,
        parties: {
            pln: 0,
            pac: 0,
            plib: 0,
            rc: 0
        }
    },
    "Puntarenas": {
        voters: 100000,
        parties: {
            pln: 0,
            pac: 0,
            plib: 0,
            rc: 0
        }
    },
    "Limon": {
        voters: 60000,
        parties: {
            pln: 0,
            pac: 0,
            plib: 0,
            rc: 0
        }
    },
    "Guanacaste": {
        voters: 90000,
        parties: {
            pln: 0,
            pac: 0,
            plib: 0,
            rc: 0
        }
    }

};
```

And I want to print the value "voters" on the console with this method:

```
function updateTable(votes) {
    table_clear();
    var table = $("#elections");
    var tbody = table.append($("<tbody/>"));
    $.each(votes, function (province, data) {
        var row = $("<tr/>");
        row.append($("<td/>")).html(province);
        $.each(data.parties, function (partyName, partyValue) {
            var td = $("<td/>");
            td.html(partyValue);
            row.append(td);
            td = $("<td/>");
            td.html();
            console.log(province.voters);
            row.append(td);

        });

        tbody.append(row);
    });

};
```

I keep getting an "undefined" on this line: "`console.log(province.voters);`

How can I access the value under this method structure?

Comment: `voters` and `parties` are properties of the same object. Why then are you accessing `data.parties` but `province.voters`? How about `data.voters`?

Comment: it probably is undefined... try using this to make sure and find what u need:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5357442/how-to-inspect-javascript-objects

Comment: @yaelalfasi: Yes. Try `console.log("Heredia".voters)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`province` is a string. It doesn't have a property `voters`.

`data` is the object you want to access (which you already do correctly for `data.parties`):

```
console.log(data.voters);
```

Comment: Yeah, you're right, I was modifying the value with another method, that's why I couldn't get the correct value, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you want to console.log(data.voters);

province is simply the string identifier such as "Puntarenas"

alternatively you could do console.log(votes[province].voters);

Answer (score 0):

To print voters for every province:

```
console.log(data.voters);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log(the_votes.Heredia.voters)
```

This will print voters in **"Heredia"**