# jQuery object to string help please

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a jquery object like so:

```
 htmlCode = $("<div id='"+data.layoutDescriptions[i].id+"'></div");
```

It seems to be missing some elements mainly when I am doing this:

```
if(data.type == "ListView"){

    htmlCode.append("<SELECT property='"+ data.property +"' size="+ data.listProps.length +" multiple>");
    i = 0;
    while(i < data.listProps.length){

        htmlCode.append("<OPTION value='"+ i+1 +"'>"+ data.listProps[i] +"</OPTION>");
        i++;
    }
    htmlCode.append("</SELECT>");

}
```

where data is a Json object.

When i do this as a string it works. e.g.
instead of

```
htmlCode.append("<OPTION value='"+ i+1 +"'>"+ data.listProps[i] +"</OPTION>");
```

i would do

```
htmlCode = htmlCode + "<OPTION value='"+ i+1 +"'>"+ data.listProps[i] +"</OPTION>";
```

I want to find out what is missing so I want to see the Object
i have tried the following:

```
alert(JQuery.htmlCode.stringify());

alert(htmlCode.html);
```

Nether work.

Any Ideas??

Thanks.

Comment: [There is no such thing as a JSON object](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Comment: What's wrong by using `.append`.

Comment: I you want to inspect the element, just do `console.log(htmlCode)` and have a look at the console. It's much easier to examine than HTML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first line of code

```
htmlCode = $("<div id='"+data.layoutDescriptions[i].id+"'></div");
```

declares the variable `htmlCode` as a jQuery object containing a single `<div>` element (defined by the HTML you passed to the function).

When you call

```
htmlCode.append("<SELECT property='"+ data.property +"' size="+ data.listProps.length +" multiple>");
```

you're appending a `<select>` element (again, defined by the HTML passed to the function) to the end of that `<div>` element, which works fine.

However, when you call

```
htmlCode.append("<OPTION value='"+ i+1 +"'>"+ data.listProps[i] +"</OPTION>");
```

you're **also** appending an `<option>` to the `<div>` element, **not** to the `<select>` element which is what you want.

It seems like you're trying to build a HTML string using a jQuery object and the `.append()` function, but that's *not what jQuery does*. jQuery works with actual elements, it just lets you pass HTML to create them.

Answer (score 1):

To get a string representation of DOM elements you can use what was posted in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2303713/how-to-serialize-dom-node-to-json).

However, using the methods provided in the other answers (console.log or Firebug) seem to be the easier choice because they work without code modifications.

Comment: That won't work since `htmlCode` contains DOM elements (circular structures and everything... it won't be possible to represent this as JSON).

Comment: Thanks for the hint. My Javascript seems to have gotten rusty. I should leave proper answers to people who know more Javscript than me ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should use Firefox/Firebug to see you objects, browse through them, change them, ...

Comment: ...or any modern browser with built in debugger/developer tools.

Comment: While not bad advice this isn't an answer to the question and should have been posted as a comment instead.

Comment: The moment I posted this I didn't have enough rep to comment :)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
if(data.type == "ListView"){
   var options;
   htmlCode.append("<SELECT property='"+ data.property +"' size="+ data.listProps.length    +" multiple></SELECT>");
   i = 0;
   while(i < data.listProps.length){

       options+="<OPTION value='"+ i+1 +"'>"+ data.listProps[i] +"</OPTION>";
       i++;
   }
   $(htmlCode).find('select').html(options);

}
```

Here is a demo [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jjay225/QsFRR/)