# Does jibx support json?

Tags: json, jibx

Does jibx support json? or is there a way to support json format using jibx marshalling?
I am trying to implement a rest service with json format support and alsi jibx marshalling support.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, JiBX does not support json marshalling/unmarshalling.
I would suggest using JiBX for the XML part and take a look at this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2303713/how-to-serialize-dom-node-to-json) subject for converting dom to json.
Don

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to generate JSON with JiBX by using Jettison:

```
StringWriter pw = new StringWriter(16384);
XMLStreamWriter w = new MappedXMLStreamWriter(mnc, pw);

// Generate XML.
IMarshallingContext mctx = bfact.createMarshallingContext();
mctx.setXmlWriter(
    new StAXWriter(bfact.getNamespaces(), w));

w.writeStartDocument();
mctx.marshalDocument(obj, "UTF-8", true);
w.writeEndDocument();

w.close();
pw.close();

return pw.toString();
```

However, all of the XML attributes will come out as strings.