# Sortable nested ul li how to save to database?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, jquery-ui

I need a database that contains a set of pages: their ID, parent ID (0 if no parents) and order.

```
+------+------------+-----------+-------------+
|  ID  |  parentID  |   order   |    Name     |
+------+------------+-----------+-------------+
|  1   |      0     |     1     |    page 1   |
|  2   |      1     |     1     |    page 2   |
|  3   |      1     |     2     |    page 3   |
|  4   |      0     |     2     |    page 4   |
|  5   |      0     |     3     |    page 5   |
+------+------------+-----------+-------------+
```

Then I have a sortable nested `ul` `li` that works with jQuery such as this

```
<ul id="sortablenested">
  <li>page 1
  <ul>
     <li>page 2</li>
     <li>page 3</li>
  </ul>
  </li>
  <li>page 4
  <ul></ul>
  </li>
  <li>page 5
  <ul></ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Now if it wasn't nested, I would just use an hidden input within each `li` tag passing an array and then go through the array with a foreach and write the position in the DB but when I move a `li` from the root `ul` to a sub `ul` with the same method it wouldn't nest it but just go through the array ignoring that it's a child.

What is the best/right method to submit the order to the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would either send whole HTML of the list tree (`innerHtml`) if it's this simple, or write JavaScript function to convert it to JSON, and send that. And parse that on server.

See [How to serialize DOM node to JSON even if there are circular references?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2303713/how-to-serialize-dom-node-to-json)

Comment: BTW proper web framework should allow this to be done out of the box. Check my favorite Wicket and consider to switch to Java ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your foreach 

`array('menu' => array(
array( father => 'page 1', link => 'url.php',
child=> array(
array(name=>'page 2', url=>'url.php'),
array(name=>'page 3', url=>'url.php'),)),
array( father => 'page 4', link => 'url.php'),
array( father => 'page 5', link => 'url.php'))
);`

Comment: Consider adding additional explanation as to what this code does and how it helps solve the original question.

Comment: I'm sorry, in this example, I took the query and turned it into an array for use in foreach.