# Get all ellements and attributes of an element root using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, circuit

I need to find all elements name in  tag and all attributes in each element by using JQuery , each element has different attributes name and value i need to know this attributes name and value but don't know how

```
    <Circuit>
<C Type="Bipolar" Name="c1">
        <Cathode row="10" col="20"/>
        <Anode row="15" col="50"/>

    </C>
    <AND Name="and1">``
        <Input>
            <Pin row="10" col="40"></Pin>
            <Pin row="20" col="40"></Pin>
        </Input>
        <Output>
            <Pin row="30" col="50"></Pin>
        </Output>
    </AND>

    <Diode Name="d1" Value="30">
        <Anode row="30" col="50"></Anode>
        <Cathode row="40" col="60"></Cathode>
    </Diode>

<R Type="Constant" Name="r1">
    <Node row="60" col="80"></Node>
    <Node row="70" col="80"></Node>
</R>    
</Circuit>
```

I'll explain what i need, first need to know all elements  (tag name) only in  tag 
o/p like this 
elements in circuit tag
C
AND 
Diode 
R

after this need to know all attributes and elements  in each element 
like this

first element (C) has 2 attribute 
first attribute is "Type"  and the  value of this attribute ="Bipolar"
second attribute is "Name" and the  value of this attribute ="c1"
 and has 2 elements 
Cathode 
Anode

and the same in each element

Comment: can you post some code which shows what you tried already (js code) ?

Comment: And what output should that generate? Have you made any attempts so far? What went wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/a/5287305/576725

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery there is the attribute matcher `[attr]`, out of many other [selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

```
$("[Name]")
```

will get you all the elements that has the attribute **Name**

you can then loop through and get the actual name with jQuerys `attr()` function

```
$("[Name]").each(function() {
    console.log($(this).attr("Name"));
    console.log($(this).attr("Value"));
});
```

### Edit

In the comments I found out that the question actually is how to serialize the whole structure into a data set. Therefore this might be a possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/a/5287305/576725

Comment: does the `this` scope of an element always contain every single attribute?

Comment: thanks for help but, I know this attributes name only in run time so i can't use this answer cause i don't know element attributes name

Comment: i need output like dictionary which contains attribute name and attribute value

Comment: I think you are searching for some deserializer that deserializes all your contents into a dataobject.

Comment: @Luke you mean, i can't do what i need by using JQuery ?

Comment: i'll explain what i need, frist need to know all elements  (tag name) only in <circuit> tag 
o/p like this 
elements in circuit tag
C
AND 
Diode 
R 

after this need to know all attributes and elements  in each element 
like this 

frist element (C) has 2 attribute 
frist attribute is "Type"  and the  value of this attribute ="Bipolar"
second attribute is "Name" and the  value of this attribute ="c1"
 and has 2 elements 
Cathode 
Anode 

and the same in each element 

you understand what i need ?

Answer (score 0):

The following prior question shows how to get all the attributes of an element using JavaScript. The same, and the elements can be obtained using jQuery:

[Get all Attributes from a HTML element with Javascript/jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048720/)

So that your code works cross-browser define your xml variable as follows:

```
var xml = $( $.parseXML( 'XML-String' ) );
```

You can the get all the elements and attributes as follows:

```
var all = xml.find('*').map(function(v,i) {
    var ux = {};
    $.each( this.attributes, function(index, node) {
         ux[ node.nodeName ] = node.nodeValue;
    });
    return $.extend({}, { nodeName: this.nodeName }, {attributes:ux});
})
.get();
```

Which should give you output that looks like:

```
[{"nodeName":"Circuit","attributes":{}},{"nodeName":"C","attributes":{"Type":"Bipolar","Name":"c1"}},{"nodeName":"Cathode","attributes":{"row":"10","col":"20"}}, ....... .. .. .. ]
```

[**JS FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/HNgd7/)