# How to get html children

Tags: jquery, html

i want to parse complete HTML children and its children wherein i will not have any attribute id placed to  tag.

For eg:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script>
     function blah(){
        alert("hi");
     }
   </script>
  <style>
     body{
         font:10px;
     }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
   <h1> My Header </h1>
   <div class="container">
       <div class="colone">Hai22</div>
       <div class="coltwo">Hai44</div>
   </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Now i would like to parse the whole html and get its children one by one and convert it into JSON string.
like

```
{
  "html":{
       "head":{
               "script":  
            .
            .
            .
            .
            .
            .
            .
}
```

Comment: Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2303713/how-to-serialize-dom-node-to-json

Comment: why you want to convert into json.. any reason?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, because the HTML (or XML-like) tree has different limitations to the Javascript/JSON object model. Specifically, every 'child' tag must be unique within the parent. This is not valid JSON:

```
"section": {
    "div": { ... },
    "div": { ... },
    "div": { ... }
}
```

You cannot have three attributes of an object called `"div"`. In the end you have to store lists of objects, something like:

```
{ 
    "tagname": "section",
    "children": [
        { "tagname": "div",
          "children": ... }
     ...
     ]
}
```

Once you get to that point the conversion is pretty much pointless. Use a standard DOM parsing library in your favourite programming language.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Tom, i will append the div id to the key value in json... i need to convert through javascript jquery... is it possible?