# Save ul list into json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I'm trying to save a list into `json` object by looping through it using a recursive function, so this is what I did so far:
**My list**:

```
<ul id="Menu">
    <li>Menu
        <ul>
            <li>Test 1</li>
            <li>Test 2
                <ul>
                    <li>Sub test 2/1</li>
                    <li>Sub test 2/2</li>
                    <li>Sub test 2/3</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Test 3</li>
            <li>Test 4</li>     
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Menu2</li>
</ul>
```

**My script:**

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    item = {};
    buildMenu($('#Menu'), item);
    menu.push(item);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(menu));  
});
var menu = [];

function buildMenu(ul, item){
    var children = [];
    ul.find('li').each(function(){
        var current = $(this);
        if(current.find('ul').length > 0){
            var newItem = {};
            buildMenu(current.find('ul'), newItem);
            children.push(newItem);
        }else{
            children.push(current.text());
        }
    });

    var txt = $(this).text();
    console.log('pushing into: '+txt);
    item[txt] = children;   
}
</script>
```

I want to save each menu and it's children inside it as json objects and send it to php but I'm having wrong output:

```
[{"MenuTest 1Test 2Sub test 2/1Sub test 2/2Sub test 2/3Test 3Test 4Menu2":[{"Test 1Test 2Sub test 2/1Sub test 2/2Sub test 2/3Test 3Test 4":["Test 1",{"Sub test 2/1Sub test 2/2Sub test 2/3":["Sub test 2/1","Sub test 2/2","Sub test 2/3"]},"Sub test 2/1","Sub test 2/2","Sub test 2/3","Test 3","Test 4"]},"Test 1",{"Sub test 2/1Sub test 2/2Sub test 2/3":["Sub test 2/1","Sub test 2/2","Sub test 2/3"]},"Sub test 2/1","Sub test 2/2","Sub test 2/3","Test 3","Test 4","Menu2"]}]
```

What's wrong with my function ?

Comment: find('li') gets not only direct child li elements, but nested li elements as well.

Comment: Just wonder. DOM is serializable to (surprise, surprise) HTML. Why would you need to save it as JSON?

Comment: @YuryTarabanko sorry I'm not following you, what do you mean ?.

Comment: I mean you have DOMElement which is easily converted into html. Why would you need to serialize DOMElement into json?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to serialize DOM node to JSON?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2303713/how-to-serialize-dom-node-to-json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what you are looking for?

```
var menu = [];
$(document).ready(function(){
    item = {};
    buildMenu($('#Menu'), item);
    menu.push(item);
    console.log(menu);  
});


function buildMenu(ul, item){
    var children = [];
    ul.children('li').each(function(){
        var current = $(this);
        if(current.children('ul').length > 0){
            var newItem = {};
            buildMenu(current.children('ul'), newItem);
            children.push(newItem);
        }else{
            children.push(current.text());
        }
    })

var txt = ul.parent().html();
txt = txt.replace(/\<ul.*[\s\S]*\<\/ul\>/g,"").trim();
console.log(txt);
item[txt] = children;      
}
```

you should only select immediate children.

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nsj3gqt5/1/

Comment: Good answer only one little problem in json object we can't find the name of the parent!
[{"":[{"":["Test 1",{"":["Sub test 2/1","Sub test 2/2","Sub test 2/3"]},"Test 3","Test 4"]},"Menu2"]}]

Comment: I have tried to name the objects, have a look. The outer most object will have blank name.

Comment: it's ok I found a solution to put names, and thank you again for you time :)

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, this script will do what you need, create menu with submenus and menu items

```
$(function() {
    var menu = [];
    buildMenu($('#Menu'), menu);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(menu));  
});

function buildMenu(item, parentList) {
    var isNode = function(item) {
        return item.is('li');
    }
    var isList = function(item) {
        return item.is('ul');
    }
    var hasChildren = function(item) {
        return item.children().length > 0;
    }

    var itemSubList = [];
    if (isNode(item)) {
        if (hasChildren(item)) {
            // This is subMenu
            // console.log("subMenu " + item.justtext().trim());
            var subMenu = {};
            subMenu[item.justtext().trim()] = itemSubList;
            parentList.push(subMenu);
        } else {
            // This is menuItem
            // console.log("menuItem " + item.text()); 
            parentList.push(item.text());
            return;
        }
    } else if (isList(item)) {
        // Processing list
        // console.log("list");
        itemSubList = parentList;
    }   
    item.children().each(function() {
        var child = $(this);
        buildMenu(child, itemSubList);
    });
}
```

Note that I used [justtext jquery plugin](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/jquery-get-text-element-without-child-element/) to get element's text without child elements, so you should include this script

```
<!-- include justtext jquery plugin -->
<script src="http://viralpatel.net/blogs/demo/jquery/get-text-without-child-element/jquery.justtext.1.0.js"></script>
```