# Convert DOM Object to Javascript Object

Tags: javascript, dom, video, merge

I came around a method to merge objects

```
Object.assign({a:1,b:2},{c:3,d:4})
```

Result is

> {a:1,b:2,c:3,d:4}

Now I have a Video DOM Object which have properties like **currentTime,duration**

So I wanted to merge DOM Video Object with a simple object like this

```
Object.assign(videoElement,{www:1})
```

Result is not what I wanted , sometimes its only the video element and sometimes its {www:1}
**So I was wondering if there is any method to convert this DOM Video Object to javascript object so that I can merge it with simple javascript objects like this**

```
Object.assign(ConvertToObject(videoElement),{www:1})
```

So I could create a new object having properties of my own object and video dom element properties
Thanks in advance and If you vote down please let me know why

Comment: Is using jQuery an option for you?

Comment: No , Sorry but I am just starting to learn it I would really prefer a pure javascript way

Comment: Related: [How to serialize DOM node to JSON even if there are circular references?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2303713/how-to-serialize-dom-node-to-json-even-if-there-are-circular-references)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `for...in` to loop all properties and create normal object from `HTML` element and use `Object.assign()` to merge two object, here is [`Fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/961/)

```js
var vid = document.querySelector('video');

function convertToObject(obj) {
  obj = {}
  for (var p in vid) {
    obj[p] = vid[p];
  }
  return obj;
}

var result = Object.assign(convertToObject(vid), {www: 1});
console.log(result.www);
```

```html
<video src=""></video>
```

Answer (score 2):

> Result is not what I wanted , sometimes its only the video element and sometimes its `{www:1}`

This should not be the case unless you're being inconsistent in your order of arguments.

`Object.assign` does not create a new object. It modifies and returns the first argument, by coping any directly-assigned enumerable properties over from subsequent argument objects.

Here are some simple examples demonstrating reliable behaviour with DOM elements:

```
var link = document.createElement('a');
Object.assign(link, { href: 'https://google.com' }) === link;
console.log(link.outerHTML);
```

```
<a href="https://google.com"></a>
```

```
var vid = document.createElement('video');
Object.assign(link, { src: 'https://example.com/video.mp4' }) === vid;
console.log(link.outerHTML);
```

```
<video src="https://example.com/video.mp4"></video>
```

If you put a different Object as the first argument, it will be returned instead.

If a property isn't being copied, it's probably because it's a "non-enumerable" property. A lot of built-in DOM Element Object properties are non-enumerable, but this isn't DOM-specific. There are non-DOM objects with the same behaviour.

Comment: I want to get all properties of the Video DOM object and sum it up with my object properties and create a new object 
so even if I change the order I'll not get what I want 
I want to have vid+link in this case (I mean properties only)

Comment: @Waqas I don't think you've fully thought through what you want here. The video element has a `.parentNode` property, which may have a `.firstChild` property pointing back to the video element. How should that be represented in the result? If you want all properties recursively, you'll capture the entire document.

Answer (score 0):

DOM objects are not pure JavaScript objects, they are a weird thing called `host objects.`  In short, host objects *may* behave differently when accessed.  They don't have to report their type correctly, nor do they have to claim methods as type `function` and other such weirdness.

When reading the polyfill method for [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), there are a few lines that might cause trouble on host objects:

```
if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(source, key)) {
    target[key] = source[key];
}
```

as such, as useful as such a short cut would be, I recommend avoiding it.

Comment: I'll check it out and then respond 
Thx for fast reply though

Comment: can you please create a function that can merge to objects and then explain a little bit 
I'll be very thankful to you.