# JSON.stringify & DOMRect

Tags: javascript, json, dom

For testing purposes I decided to test a function I have written which returns a `DOMRect` object.

In the console I can see that the DOMRect is intact and has all of its properties. However, when I have `JSON.stringify(rect)` (where rect is the variable with the return result), I get the empty object `{}`.

I don’t know whether that means that there’s something special about a `DOMRect`, or whether `JSON.stringify` doesn’t do what I thought it would do, which is to serialize the properties of an object.

The question is: why won’t JSON.stringify work on a `DOMRect` (and will it also fail on some other obects?

FWIW, I am testing on a current Mac, and have tried both Firefox and Webkit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JSON.stringify()` cannot be used on any DOM element - you will need to pull out the data you want and place into an Object. Previously `JSON.stringify()` on DOM nodes used to result in this error:

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
```

Now Chrome, Firefox, etc. all output `"{}"`

Comment: Could you clarify that point? `JSON.stringify` doesn’t work on _any_ dom object? Fair enough, I suppose, but it seems odd — it’s not as if the values are dynamic. The circular structure message seems stranger.

Comment: correct - `JSON.stringify()` will not work on any DOM node. see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2303713/how-to-serialize-dom-node-to-json-even-if-there-are-circular-references

Comment: Thanks for your help. All I really needed was the content, so I have found it convenient copy the `DOMRect` content into a new object. It also gives me the chance to customise it a bit and polyfill for Certain Browsers.

Answer (score -1):

JSON.stringify only works on structured data. It does not allow the stringification of functions.

Answer (score -1):

**DOMRect is a function** so, JSON.stringify() will not allowed because DOMRect contains 'Virtual' properties. JSON.stringify() depends on Object.key(attr).