# How to hide my chrome extension source code

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Recently, i have made a chrome ext, but anyone can read its source code by rename the crx to zip and extract it, how i secure my SC ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Encrypt Chrome-extension?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4426132/encrypt-chrome-extension)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only way to prevent anyone with your extension from seeing the logic is to move it out of the extension that runs on a user computer and into a web service that the extension accesses.

Since this will slow down the works quite a bit, you should only do this for the really valuable parts of your code.

Answer (score 5):

The best (and only?) way would be to [obfuscate your JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194397/how-can-i-obfuscate-javascript).

edit: Chrome Webstore does not allow you to obfuscate your JavaScript code. You can read it in the [Chrome Webstore program policies](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/program_policies)

> Code Readability Requirements:
>
> Developers must not obfuscate code or conceal functionality of their 
>   extension. This also applies to any external code or resource fetched by the 
>   extension package. Minification is allowed, including the following forms:
>
> - Removal of whitespace, newlines, code comments, and block delimiters
> - Shortening of variable and function names
> - Collapsing files together

Answer (score 2):

You can use **Google Firebase API** and related other **storage services** for write secure/safe business logic, because your google extension code is always open to show for every one....

:::: *Example for your more help* ::::

**key-value from extension JS code** ----- Transfer to Server ----> **Firebase API perform your logics** ---- send back to ----> **extension JS code**

FireBase is Free and light weight and perfect for business logic