# Content Security Policy getJSON

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension, getjson, content-security-policy

I'm sorry for my english,

I have this following code in my HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugin.js"></script>
```

In my JS:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.getJSON("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/"+"NameOfStreamer"+"?callback=?",function(c) {

        if (c.stream == null) {
            $("p").text("Stream offline, n'hésitez pas à me rejoindre sur les réseaux sociaux afficher ci-dessous.");

        } else {

            $("p").text("Stream online, rejoins moi sur Domingo.tv en cliquant sur le lien ci dessous");

        }
    });
});
```

In my manifest :

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Getting started example",
  "description": "This extension shows a Google Image search result for the current page",
  "version": "1.0",
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },

  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "https://ajax.googleapis.com/",
  ]
}
```

And i obtain that :

```
Refused to load the script 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/NameOfStreamer?callback=jQuery11120590793181443587_1429560015317&_=1429560015318' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:".
```

I would like to know how i can resolve that pls.

Comment: you're doing cross-domain ajax request. you need either jsonp, or the appropriate CORS headers to allow it.

Comment: Incorrect duplicate. The issue here IS jsonp. It needs to be dropped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in trying to use JSONP, which is not needed.

You want to receive data, not a script to execute. JSONP is a trick to bypass the inability to make cross-domain requests if the remote server does not allow it; however, Chrome extensions have [host permissions that bypass cross-domain restrictions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr#requesting-permission).

1. Add cross-domain permissions for the API you're using.

   ```
     "permissions": [
       "activeTab",
       "https://ajax.googleapis.com/*",
       "https://api.twitch.tv/*"
     ]
   ```
2. Call the API **without** the callback parameter:

   ```
   $.getJSON("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/"+"NameOfStreamer", 
     function(c) {
       if (c.stream == null) {
         /*...*/
       }
     }
   );
   ```

Comment: So , i try this code and i don't have the same error : XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/NameOfStreamer. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'chrome-extension://ennobinmkifbonghaaoekogblngkcdja' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: In your JS file inside Document.ready function. You need to replace $.getJSON method with above code and handle success as per your requirement.

Comment: Did you add the permission? Did you reload the extension afterwards?

Comment: Yes i did as you told me. But now i have this error :/

Comment: Triple-check your manifest. This error should not appear if the permission is added correctly. Did you forget the `*`?

Comment: It's good, i reloaded the extension after and it works. Thanks you !! But , another question , do you know how i can hide this code , because everybody can enter with just a right click ^^ ?

Comment: Basically, you can't. It will always be accessible, unless you offload part of the logic to a remote server. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4426132/encrypt-chrome-extension), for instance.