# function name in json response - not working

Tags: php, jquery, json

I am trying to send a function in JSON response and tried to alert that function in js. Below is the code.

**JS:**

```
$('input').keyup(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "sample.php",
        dataType : 'json',
        data: 'val='+$('input').val(),
        success: function(response){

         var json = transport.responseText.evalJSON();
         alert(json.function()); // => **should alert 'foo bar' - but not**
        }
    });
});
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
// Our sample array
$foo = array(
  'string'  => 'bar',
  'function'=> 'function(){return "foo bar";}'
);
$value_arr = array();
$replace_keys = array();
foreach($foo as $key => &$value){
  // Look for values starting with 'function('
  if(strpos($value, 'function(')===0){
    // Store function string.
    $value_arr[] = $value;
    // Replace function string in $foo with a 'unique' special key.
    $value = '%' . $key . '%';
    // Later on, we'll look for the value, and replace it.
    $replace_keys[] = '"' . $value . '"';
  }
}

// Now encode the array to json format
$json = json_encode($foo);

/* $json looks like:
{
  "number":1,
  "float":1.5,
  "array":[1,2],
  "string":"bar",
  "function":"%function%"
}
*/
// Replace the special keys with the original string.
$json = str_replace($replace_keys, $value_arr, $json);

// Send to to the client
echo $json;

/* This echoes the following string:
{
  "string":"bar",
  "function":function(){return "foo bar";}
}
*/
?>
```

what am I doing wrong in the above? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: always remember that json is just text that is structured.

Answer (score 5):

[JSON](http://json.org) doesn't have any representation for functions. It's a data notation. Even if you trick PHP into sending a function (as you appear to be trying to do), a *proper* JSON deserializer on the client will throw an exception (ideally). Some very naive ones that rely on `eval` may pass the function through, but at that point, you're not using JSON, you're using JavaScript.

If you want to send back *code*, you need to send back JavaScript.

Separately, on this line:

```
alert(json.function());
```

...you have a syntax error. `function` is a reserved word in JavaScript. You can't use it as a property name literal. If you create a property with the name "function" (which you can, but probably shouldn't), to access it you have to use the string notation for accessing properties:

```
alert(json["function"]());
```

See also [Gaby's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6213095/function-name-in-json-response-not-working/6213156#6213156), you seem to have mixed some Prototype code (`evalJSON`) into things.

Answer (score 4):

A function is not a valid data type in JSON. What you can do is to send a function expression as string:

```
{
  "string": "bar",
  "function":"function(){return \"foo bar\";}"
}
```

And then use `eval`:

```
var f = eval(response['function']);
```

**But I would not recommend doing so.** It is horrible, complex, not easy to understand or to maintain. It is basically the worst you can do.

What problem are you trying to solve with that?

---

If you have to send JavaScript from the server, then do so (don't return JSON), and use `script` as `dataType`.

Comment: `eval` and Functions encoded as a string of code in json. That's horrible :(

Comment: +1 *A value can be a string in double quotes, or a number, or true or false or null, or an object or an array. These structures can be nested.* http://json.org/

Answer (score 1):

You are obviously using code from http://solutoire.com/2008/06/12/sending-javascript-functions-over-json/

But they are using [prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/) and not [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) ..

The line `transport.responseText.evalJSON();` means nothing in jQuery ..

Also have a look at http://json.org/ and you will see that functions is not supposed to go in JSON .. For more explanation read [Is it valid to define functions in JSON results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001449/is-it-valid-to-define-functions-in-json-results)