# Passing lambda expression to controller using ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, json, lambda

I wonder if its possible to pass a lambda expression from the view back to the controller
for example I have a model:

```
public class ExpressionModel<T>
{
    public Expression<Func<T, string>> Expression { get; set; }
}
```

A controller to pass the model to the view would look something like this:

```
public ViewResult Index()
{
    var expressionModel =  new ExpressionModel<SomeClass>();
    expressionModel.Expression = r => r.SomeStringProperty;

    return View(expressionModel);
}
```

Now the view has a model:

```
@model ExpressionModel
```

Now using Ajax I want to pass back the model to a controller

```
var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));

$.ajax({ url: "@someControllerUrl",  
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(model),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data.success);
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("error");
    }
 });
```

The controller method that gets the expression model from the view would look something like this

```
[HttpPost]
public ViewResult Index(ExpressionModel expressionModel)
{
    return View();
}
```

Is this even possible using ajax? Or can you only post back standard types like int, string, bool (or any combinations of them in a list or inside another class)? 
If it is not possible, can I then maybe cast a string to a lambda expression somehow?

Answer (score 2):

This question seems similar to yours:
[Is it valid to define functions in JSON results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001449/is-it-valid-to-define-functions-in-json-results)

In short: no, you can only post back standard types.

At length:
AJAX is just passing HTTP data back to your server asynchronously via Javascript. That data can be whatever you like. The server then has to decide how to parse that data. Casting user input (*anything* coming from the client should be considered user input) to a lambda expression is a *bad idea.* It would allow a user to execute arbitrary code on your server.

What you *should* do instead is create a server-side list of valid lambda expressions and then pass back the index corresponding to the lambda you want to use. That way you have total control over the code that gets run on your server. Or, barring that, employ some simple input parsing that constructs the lambda from a string. But be very careful with that, since it can be pretty easy to create a security hole that way.